# Query to find the duplicates between the name and number in table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT count(*), lower(name), number
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY lower(name), number
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

input tb1

```
slno name number
1    aaa   111
2    Aaa   111
3    abb   221
4    Abb   121
5    cca   131
6    cca   141
7    abc   222
8    cse   222
```

This query can just find the duplicates in the number and names which are same but it wont be able find the duplicates in the 3 and 4th row!!!

```
 SELECT count(*), lower(name)
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY lower(name)
    HAVING count(lower(name)) > 1
```

this query can find all the duplicates in name!!! it works perfectly

```
 SELECT count(*), number
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY number
    HAVING count(number) > 1
```

this query can find all the duplicates in number!!! it works perfectly

I want a query which can find all the duplicates in both name and number whether the name consists of lower case and upper case

```
output
name number count
2    111     aaa
2    ---     abb
2    ---     cca
2    222     ---
```

Comment: what records do you want to get? specifically the `slno`.

Comment: @JohnWoo need to find all the duplicates for names and number

Comment: your `abb` - `221` and `Abb` - `121` are unique records according to your group by clause, since you are grouping on both. If you just want to get duplicates based on name, then remove `number` from your SQL statement

Comment: How would you go about it, when a row is duplicate in regard to its `name` with one row and duplicate in regard to its `number` with another row? Show your desired result do make clear what you are after.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  but both the names are the same in 3rd and 4 th row

Comment: Even if you switch the column names `name` and `count`, the added  result doesn't quite pan out. The count in the first row of the result is not well defined. Add up duplicates for name *and* number? Or choose the maximum between the two? What would your get if the first row has 2 dupes on `name` and 5 dupes on `number`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Updated question

"Get duplicate on both number and name"  ...  "name and number as different column"
Rows can be counted twice here!

```
SELECT lower(name), NULL AS number, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY lower(name)
HAVING count(*) > 1

UNION  ALL
SELECT NULL, number, count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY number
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85a7b/1)

#### Original question

The problem is that the query groups by

```
GROUP  BY lower(name), number
```

As row 3 and 4 have a *different* `number`, they are not the same for this query.

If you want to ignore different numbers for this query, try something like:

```
SELECT lower(name)
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY lower(name)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: if i want for both number and name !!

Comment: @soul: That's a contradictory requirement. You have to define more clearly what you want. Like I commented above.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT number) AS distinct_numbers 
FROM tb1
GROUP  BY lower(name at line 3

Comment: `array_agg()` was a PostgreSQL aggregate function. Your previous question was tagged Postgres and I missed that you retagged this one. You would use `group_concat()` in MySQL. Anyway, removed the optional line.

Comment: fine will check it and let u know

Answer (score 1):

With a little work we can show counts for both `name` and `number` in one column:

```
select NameOrNumber, count(*) as Count
from (
    select name as NameOrNumber from tb1
    union all
    select number from tb1
) a
group by NameOrNumber
having count(NameOrNumber) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77c41/5)

**Output #1:**

```
| NAMEORNUMBER | COUNT |
------------------------
|          111 |     2 |
|          aaa |     2 |
|          abb |     2 |
|          cca |     2 |
```

If you want the output in separate columns, you can do something like this:

```
select distinct if(t1.name = t2.name, t1.name, null) as DUPLICATE_Name,
    if(t1.number = t2.number, t1.number, null) as DUPLICATE_Number
from tb1 t1
inner join tb1 t2 on (t1.name = t2.name or t1.number = t2.number)
    and t1.slno <> t2.slno
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77c41/13)

**Output #2:**

```
| DUPLICATE_NAME | DUPLICATE_NUMBER |
-------------------------------------
|            Aaa |              111 |
|            Abb |           (null) |
|            cca |           (null) |
```

Comment: yup this query works fine... but one little change i want name and number as different column

Comment: updated my question!!! first query was working fine!! second query just gives only one name in both name and number column