# Symfony2, doctrine and pgsql, search with accent insensitive

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 and i have a simple query with createQueryBuilder like :

```
            $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select(array('a'))
                    ->from('MyProjectBundle:Account', 'a')
                    ->where('LOWER(a.firstname) LIKE LOWER(?1)')
                    ->setParameters(array(1 => '%'.$search.'%'));
            return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I'm using pdo_pgsql for my database, how can i add an accent insensitive for this query ?

For now, i just have the lower, but i need to retrieve the account `"Clément"` when `$search` is `"cle"`. This is for an autocomplete form (like facebook when you search someone)

Comment: No hehe, `->setParameters(array(1 => '%'.iconv($search).'%'));`

Comment: Yeah, but i need to do the same for a.firstname...

Comment: `SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';`

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't read.... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596638/function-to-remove-accents-in-postgresql

Comment: unnacent doesn't work with Symfony2 and Doctrine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own DQL function and then register it in your `config.yml` file. Registering in configuration can be done this way:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        dql:
            string_functions:
                test_string: Acme\HelloBundle\DQL\StringFunction
                second_string: Acme\HelloBundle\DQL\SecondStringFunction
            numeric_functions:
                test_numeric: Acme\HelloBundle\DQL\NumericFunction
            datetime_functions:
                test_datetime: Acme\HelloBundle\DQL\DatetimeFunction
```

Creating your own DQL function is a bit wider problematics, but it is well explained in [DQL User Defined Functions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, to retrieve values from a database in a diacritic-insensitive way, you should make sure that the collation of your fields are set to something neutral, like for example `utf8_general_ci`.

But for PostgreSQL, collations work in a different way.
Perhaps this answer may help you:
[Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations)

Comment: I know this topic, but unaccent doesn't work with Symfony2 and Doctrine