# Add accents to a word in portuguese using rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following string in portuguese:
calça

But when a use search using calca I need to convert to calça
Is there a gem ou a dict I can use to convert non accents strings to words with correct accents in portuguese?

Comment: Typically this is part of a search library/engine. Are you using ElasticSearch or postgres or... something else?

Comment: For example, elasticsearch has many built-in 'normalizers' https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html, specifically their `asciifolding` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Postgres supports `unaccent` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596638/function-to-remove-accents-in-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

To remove accents in ruby: [Ruby method to remove accents from UTF-8 international characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686752/ruby-method-to-remove-accents-from-utf-8-international-characters)

To remove accents in elastic search: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html

To remove accents in postgres: [Function to remove accents in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596638/function-to-remove-accents-in-postgresql)