# Ignore special characters in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, unaccent

I have a table named `artists` with a record with the value 'Miró' in the name column. When I do this request:

```
SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE name = 'Miró'
```

I have one result, so it works.

Now, when I do this request (without the special `ó`) :

```
SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE name = 'Miro'
```

I don't find anything. I want to ignore the special char. Is there a way to do it?
I have postgres 9.1.9.

Comment: Maybe you could just remove the special characters from the string you're searching.. and maybe use `LIKE` instead of `=` .. something like `WHERE name like 'MIR_'

Comment: Well, the two characters are different. So, you'd probably need something like `SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE name like 'Mir_'`

Comment: I think that there is already a solution existing at stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a more targeted pattern matching, you can use the function **`unaccent()`**, provided by the additional module [**unaccent**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html):

```
SELECT * FROM artists WHERE unaccent(name) = 'Miro';
```

To make this fast, create a functional index. You have to overcome the obstacle that the function is only `STABLE`, not `IMMUTABLE`. I wrote a comprehensive answer with instructions (including installation) and links recently:
[Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using LIKE instead...

```
SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE name like 'Mir%'
```

Comment: Yes, it could work but I dont want to replace every charaters. If type Miro, I don't want to have Miru, Miri or Mira.

Comment: Makes sense. Looks like Erwin had a great answer.