# Indexing an array for full text search

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I am trying to index documents to be searchable on their tag array.

```
CREATE INDEX doc_search_idx ON documents
      USING gin( 
    to_tsvector('english', array_to_string(tags, ' ')) ||
    to_tsvector('english', coalesce(notes, '')))
)
```

Where `tags` is a `(ci)text[]`. However, PG will refuse to index `array_to_string` because it [is not always immutable](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1280364669.31397.8.camel@jdavis-ux.asterdata.local).

```
PG::InvalidObjectDefinition: ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

I've tried creating a homebrew `array_to_string` immutable function, but I feel like playing with fire as I don't know what I'm doing. Any way not to re-implement it?

Looks like I could just repackage the same function and label it immutable, but looks like [there are risks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18220761/720164) when doing that.

How do I index the array for full-text search?

Comment: Looks like I found a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29639955/720164) though it doesn't say how the function is made.

Answer (score 14):

In my initial answer I suggested a plain cast to text: `tags::text`. However, while most casts to text from basic types are defined `IMMUTABLE`, this it is not the case for array types. Obviously because ([quoting Tom Lane in a post to pgsql-general](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27130.1323443398@sss.pgh.pa.us)):

> Because it's implemented via array_out/array_in rather than any more
> direct method, and those are **marked stable because they potentially
> invoke non-immutable element I/O functions**.

Bold emphasis mine.

We can work with that. The general case cannot be marked as `IMMUTABLE`. But for the case at hand (cast `citext[]` or `text[]` to `text`) we can safely assume immutability. Create a simple `IMMUTABLE` SQL function that wraps the function. However, the appeal of my simple solution is mostly gone now. You might as well wrap `array_to_string()` (like you already pondered) for which similar considerations apply.

For `citext[]` (create separate functions for `text[]` if needed):

Either (based on a plain cast to `text`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ciarr2text(citext[]) 
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS 'SELECT $1::text';
```

This is faster.
Or (using `array_to_string()` for a result without curly braces):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ciarr2text(citext[]) 
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$SELECT array_to_string($1, ',')$$;
```

This is a bit more correct.
Then:

```
CREATE INDEX doc_search_idx ON documents USING gin (
   to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(f_ciarr2text(tags), '')
                || ' ' || COALESCE(notes,'')));
```

I did *not* use the polymorphic type `ANYARRAY` like [in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212590/939860), because I know `text[]` or `citext[]` are safe, but I can't vouch for *all* other array types.

Tested in Postgres 9.4 and works for me.

I added a space between the two strings to avoid false positive matches across the concatenated strings. There is an [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX).

If you sometimes want to search just `tags` or just `notes`, consider a multicolumn index instead:

```
CREATE INDEX doc_search_idx ON documents USING gin (
             to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(f_ciarr2text(tags), '')
          ,  to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(notes,''));
```

**The risks** you are referring to apply to temporal functions mostly, which are used in the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18220761/939860). If time zones (or just the type `timestamptz`) are involved, results are not actually immutable. We do not lie about immutability here. Our functions are *actually* `IMMUTABLE`. Postgres just can't tell from the general implementation it uses.

#### Related

Often people think they need [text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html), while similarity search with trigram indexes would be a better fit:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Not relevant in this exact case, but while working with `citext`, consider this:

- [Index on column with data type citext not used](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/105244/3684)

Comment: Actually, I've just had the chance to try this, and looks like PG interprets the `::text` as not immutable. `ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
: CREATE INDEX doc_search_idx ON documents
      USING gin(    to_tsvector('english', coalesce(tag_cache::text, ''))
)`. Have you tried it?

Comment: I can create the index just fine, but I find that for some reason Postgres won't use it. EXPLAIN ANALYZE always shows a seq scan. The index works fine if I leave out the array column.

Comment: @stickfigure: Ask a new question with specifics if you can't figure it out. Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for context and drop a comment here to link forward.

Comment: This "non-immutable element I/O functions" sounds mysterious.  What's an example of how `array_to_string` would have non-immutable behavior between one query and another on some array type?

Comment: @Andy: The text representation of some data types depends on session settings. Like `timestamptz`. Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/eDJekbv8. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384767/939860

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I see, so I guess Postgres function overloading currently doesn't make it possible to declare overloads IMMUTABLE for applicable element types?

Comment: @Andy: That's possible. But `array_to_string()` is a single polymorphic function. (Well, there is a 2nd variant with 3 args.) You can create such overloaded functions, even with `LANGUAGE internal` or `LANGUAGE c`, but you need superuser privileges, and it gets confusing and error-prone quickly. I would go with distinct function names. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384767/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860 For anything more, please start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my naive solution, to wrap it and call it immutable, as suspected.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION immutable_array_to_string(arr ANYARRAY, sep TEXT)
    RETURNS text
    AS $$
      SELECT array_to_string(arr, sep);
    $$
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
  ;
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the index is actually used? Indexes I create this way aren't being used.