# Create an immutable clone of concat_ws

Tags: postgresql, function, concatenation, concat-ws

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@tylercubell/postgres-immutable-concat-in-indexes-d9fe1b94922f) shows an example of how to create a `immutable_concat` function in Pg:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat(VARIADIC "any")
  RETURNS text AS 'text_concat'
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE
```

I'd like to do the same with `concat_ws` and the corresponding `text_concat_ws` does exist, however, the following just crashes the process:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(VARIADIC "any")
  RETURNS text AS 'text_concat_ws'
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE
```

Update: The siguature of `immutable_concat_ws` should be `(glue, *parts)`, one glue (text or varchar) and one or more parts (text, varchar or null).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which kinds of arguments do you want to feed to your function - and what's the use case where you concatenate multiple expressions for an index. Might be an XY problem, and a more efficient solution around two corners. The function you show here is not only wrong (missing 1st parameter), it's also potentially hazardous. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860

Comment: I've added the signature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Firstly**, the function requires *two* parameters in the definition, like Richard already suggested, and you updated your question accordingly.

**Secondly**, you can create that function with `"any"` input using `LANGUAGE internal`. Does not mean that you should, though.

`concat_ws()` is only `STABLE` for a reason. Among others, the text representation of `date` or `timestamp` depends on locale / datestyle settings, so the result is not *immutable*. Indexes building on this could silently break. Restricted to `text` input, it's safe to declare it `IMMUTABLE`.
Since you only need `text` input (or `varchar`, which has an implicit cast to `text`), limit it to your use case and be safe:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'text_concat_ws';
```

Crating a `LANGUAGE internal` function requires **superuser** privileges. If that's not an option, the next best thing would be an SQL function like:

- [PostgreSQL full text search on many columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164081/3684)

Mark it as `PARALLEL SAFE` in Postgres 9.6 or later (it qualifies!) to enable parallelism when involving this function. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-safety.html#PARALLEL-LABELING)

> all user-defined functions are assumed to be parallel unsafe unless otherwise marked.

Resist the temptation to do things like this `immutable_concat_ws('|', now()::text, 'foo')`. This would reintroduce said dependencies in the call.

Related:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

Comment: I'm only dealing with text and NULL values here, so immutable should be fine. Thanks a bunch for the help!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you're mapping to internal "C" functions, which I must admit I've never done myself.

However, `text_concat_ws` is "with separator" so it doesn't just take a variadic list of text arguments - it [takes a separator THEN the variadic list of text](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/varlena_8c.html#a34f70638025a826021f7e90f492f6ff2) arguments. Adjust your function definition accordingly.

If you're going to be doing this, you probably want to hook a debugger up to the backend or run it single process if that's practical.

Also - I just found the doxygen interface to the PostgreSQL source-code replying to your question. Thanks :-)