# Why am I getting a an error when creating a generated column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, string-concatenation, calculated-columns

```
CREATE TABLE my_app.person
(
    person_id smallserial NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(50),
    last_name character varying(50),
    full_name character varying(100) generated always as (concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)) STORED,
    birth_date date,
    created_timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);
```

Error: generation expression is not immutable

The goal is to populate the first name and last into the full name column.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `concat()` function is not `IMMUTABLE` (only `STABLE`) because it can invoke datatype output functions (like `timestamptz_out`) that depend on locale settings. [Tom Lane (core developer) explains it here.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3361.1410026366%40sss.pgh.pa.us)

And `first_name || ' ' || last_name` is ***not*** equivalent to `concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)` while at least one column can be `NULL`.

Detailed explanation:

- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310986/combine-two-columns-and-add-into-one-new-column/12320369#12320369)

#### Solution

To make it work, exactly the way you demonstrated:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  person_id smallserial PRIMARY KEY
, first_name varchar(50)
, last_name  varchar(50)
, full_name  varchar(101) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
                         (CASE WHEN first_name IS NULL THEN last_name
                               WHEN last_name  IS NULL THEN first_name
                               ELSE first_name || ' ' || last_name END) STORED
, ...
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bcbd57d1d47ec6d6188684d9509cef9e)*

The `CASE` expression is as fast as it gets - substantially faster than multiple concatenation and function calls. And exactly correct.

**Or**, *if you know what you are doing* and have the necessary privileges, **create an `IMMUTABLE` concat function** as demonstrated here (to replace the `CASE` expression):

- [Create an immutable clone of concat_ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372666/create-an-immutable-clone-of-concat-ws/54384767#54384767)

Aside: `full_name` needs to be `varchar(101)` (50+50+1) to make sense. Or just use `text` columns instead. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

#### General Advice

The best solution depends on how you plan to deal with NULL values (and empty strings) exactly. I would probably **not** add a generated column. That's typically more expensive and error prone overall than to concatenate the full name on the fly. Consider a view, or a function encapsulating the concatenation logic.

Related:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)
- [Store common query as column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165450/store-common-query-as-column/11166268#11166268)

Answer (score 6):

This works with the `||` operator:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    person_id smallserial NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(50),
    last_name character varying(50),
    full_name character varying(100) generated always as (first_name || ' ' || last_name) STORED,
    birth_date date,
    created_timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);
```

I am not sure of the technical reasons why `concat()` is considered mutable, but `||` is not.

If you want to handle `NULL` values in the columns, then it is a little more complicated.  I might recommend:

```
trim(both ' ' from
     (' ' || coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '')
     )
    )
```

Of course, this isn't *exactly* the same as your expression, because it removes spaces from the beginning and end of the names.

Comment: Yes it doesn't make sense. Thank you!

Comment: The replacement is not equivalent.