# Computed text column as concat (sum of strings) of two other columns

Tags: python, postgresql, database-design, sqlalchemy, calculated-columns

I want to have a table in which I have unique pairs of `source` and `source_id`. But I also need single column unique `id` to make API more simple.

I am trying to have `id` column as concat of two other columns:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Computed, Column, Integer, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    id = Column(Text, Computed("source || source_id"), primary_key=True)
    source = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    source_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=True)
```

I first tried to use `contcat()` but it gave me error: `generation expression is not immutable`.

I [learned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249404/why-am-i-getting-a-an-error-when-creating-a-generated-column-in-postgresql) that it can't work and I should switch to `||`. But `||` gives me the same error. How to solve it?

Below is error log which contains generated SQL.

```sql
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidObjectDefinition) generation expression is not immutable

[SQL:
CREATE TABLE product (
        id TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (source || source_id) STORED NOT NULL,
        source TEXT NOT NULL,
        source_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name TEXT,
        CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Comment: I would have try to apply this `concat()` in an `_init_`method. Anyway, the question is interesting, but I would strongly recommend you do NOT use this kind of method for IDs. An auto calculated field will be much more efficient, and you can add a calculated field if there is a need of it anyway.

Comment: @Christophe do you mean that it is better idea to have: `source` and `source_id` as composite PK and `id` as autoincrement, not null, unique, Integer?

Comment: I would not even create a composite PK. You could create an index, but for the PK I really prefer to have an autoincrement `id`. In my environment, we use aggregations for ids, to have an 'explicit link with the source', and it's a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly cast `source_id` as `text` and it works.

```sql
CREATE TABLE product
(
  id TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (source || source_id::text) STORED NOT NULL,
  source TEXT NOT NULL,
  source_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

in Python:

```py
    id = Column(Text, Computed("source || source_id::text"), primary_key=True)
```

BTW isn't `id` redundant? What about `CONSTRAINT pk_product PRIMARY KEY (source, source_id)`, i.e.

```py
    source = Column(Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    source_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

Comment: Yes, `id` is redundant, but it allows me to make ForeignKeys and API calls easier. Although I will try to switch to composite PK / composite FK and get rid of `id` as you say, it seems to be the right way of doing things.

Comment: After trying composite PK and seeing its flaws I decided to go with single autoincrement `id` PK which was suggested by @Christophe

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
CREATE TABLE product(
    CONCAT (source, source_id) AS "TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS",
    ...
)
```

directly in your SQL statement?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in SQLAlchemy