# Postgres generated column is not immutable

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, generated-columns

I am adding some columns to a table, and want a generated column that combines them together that I'll use for a unique index. When I try to add the column, I get the error `ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable`.

I followed the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249404/why-am-i-getting-a-an-error-when-creating-a-generated-column-in-postgresql), and am specifically using `CASE` and `||` for string concatenation, which are supposed to be `immutable`.

```
ALTER TABLE tag
  ADD COLUMN prefix VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  ADD COLUMN middle BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ADD COLUMN postfix VARCHAR(4), -- nullable
  -- VARCHAR size is 4 prefix + 19 middle + 4 postfix + 2 delimiter
  ADD COLUMN tag_id VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (CASE WHEN postfix IS NULL THEN prefix || '-' || middle
          ELSE prefix || '-' || middle || '-' || postfix
          END
    ) STORED;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_tag_tag_id ON tag(tag_id);
```

---

In the [postgres mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17503.1562770072%40sss.pgh.pa.us), one of the contributors clarifies that:

> integer-to-text coercion, [...] isn't necessarily
> immutable

However, he doesn't share an integer-to-text function that is immutable. Does anyone know if one exists?

Comment: Good question. I never really got to understand why this example works for VARCHARs but not for INTs.

Comment: Seems that it works with cast to `text`, i.e.   `middle::text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test in 14.1 shows that the cause is the implicite conversion of the `bigint` column to `text` in the concatenation (even without a `case`)

An explicite cast to `text` produces no error - `middle::text`

```
ALTER TABLE tag
  ADD COLUMN prefix VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  ADD COLUMN middle BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ADD COLUMN postfix VARCHAR(4), -- nullable
  -- VARCHAR size is 4 prefix + 19 middle + 4 postfix + 2 delimiter
  ADD COLUMN tag_id VARCHAR(29) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS
    (CASE WHEN postfix IS NULL THEN prefix || '-' || middle::text
          ELSE prefix || '-' || middle::text || '-' || postfix
          END
    ) STORED;
```

Answer (score 5):

Marmite Bomber's answer shows the soluion; let me add an explanation.

There are two concatenation operators for `text`:

```
SELECT oid, oprname,
       oprleft::regtype,
       oprright::regtype,
       oprcode
FROM pg_operator
WHERE oprname = '||'
  AND oprleft = 'text'::regtype;

 oid  │ oprname │ oprleft │  oprright   │  oprcode   
══════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════════╪════════════
  654 │ ||      │ text    │ text        │ textcat
 2779 │ ||      │ text    │ anynonarray │ textanycat
(2 rows)
```

The first operator concatenates `text` with `text`, the second concatenates `text` with anything else.

Let's examine the volatility of these two functions:

```
SELECT oid, proname, provolatile
FROM pg_proc
WHERE pronamespace = 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace
  AND proname IN ('textcat', 'textanycat');

 oid  │  proname   │ provolatile 
══════╪════════════╪═════════════
 1258 │ textcat    │ i
 2003 │ textanycat │ s
(2 rows)
```

So if you concatenate `text` and `bigint`, that operation is not `IMMUTABLE`, but casting the `bigint` to `text` first makes the operation `IMMUTABLE`.

It is not because of concatenating with integers that this operator is not immutable. But `anynonarray` could be any data type like `timestamp with time zone`, whose string representation depends on the current setting of `timezone`.

Comment: Thanks for the inner look at the engine. However, I still fail to conceptually understand why concatenating an INT could make it immutable. Can you show an example? Or... maybe there should be a third operator option for the (text. int) variation?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the note. IMHO, I think the second case should be separated in two different ones, since BIGINT behaves quite differently compared to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Comment: @TheImpaler Are you suggesting that we have a concatenation function for each data type (or at least for each preferred data type)? You are welcome to submit a patch...

Comment: You are right. Complaning is easy; taking action, on the other hand, requires much more effort. Cannot do it right now, but I would love to help with PostgreSQL in the future. Thanks for the *scolding* ;)