# Generated column of tsvector for text array in Postgres (Supabase)

Tags: postgresql, supabase, tsvector

in Postgres (Supabase) I am trying to automatically generate a column from another column which contains a text array of short title variants.

The tsvector works just fine and as expected. The other possibility which would be to use array_to_tsvector is not an option as short title text array contains not just single words but variants of short titles (sentences).

```sql
alter table "MOVIES"  
add column fts_short_title  
tsvector  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (  
to_tsvector('simple', 
array_to_string( title_short,' '::text)) 
 ) STORED;
```

but I get this error

```bash
Failed to run sql query: generation expression is not immutable
```

On the other hand I was successful when adding such a column for JSONB of full titles for different languages

```sql
alter table "MOVIES"  
add column fts  
tsvector  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 
to_tsvector('simple', 
coalesce(title->>'en', '') || ' ' ||  
coalesce(title->>'de', '') || ' ' ||  
coalesce(title->>'it', '') || ' ' ||  
coalesce(title->>'fr', ''))
  ) STORED;
```

Thank you very much for any tip and help.
.. SQL is rather new to me, have used only from MongoDB previously, so sorry for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define `immutable` wrappers for otherwise non-immutable functions. [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6JGqwL-T)

```sql
create or replace function array_to_string_immutable (
    arg text[], 
    separator text,
    null_string text default null) 
returns text immutable parallel safe language sql as $$
select array_to_string(arg,separator,null_string) $$;

alter table "MOVIES"  
add column fts_short_title  
tsvector  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (  
to_tsvector('simple', 
array_to_string_immutable( title_short,' '::text)) 
 ) STORED;
table "MOVIES";
```

While the `textcat()` function behind `||` operator is immutable, I'm pretty sure `array_to_string()` is only `stable` [for the same reason `concat()` is](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3361.1410026366%40sss.pgh.pa.us) so you need to be reasonably careful with where you use this workaround.

You could do the same for the other column to use a [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) and avoid the repeated `||' '||coalesce()`:

```sql
create or replace function concat_ws_immutable (
    separator text,
    variadic arg text[]) 
returns text immutable parallel safe language sql as $$
select concat_ws(separator,variadic arg) $$;

alter table "MOVIES"  
add column fts  
tsvector  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 
 to_tsvector('simple',concat_ws_immutable(' ',title->>'en',title->>'de',title->>'it',title->>'fr'))
) STORED;
```

You are also free to do pretty much whatever you want, however you want to the column in a [plpgsql function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) used by a [`trigger after insert or update on "MOVIES"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: You are brilliant, the function works like a charm!!!. Thank you very much for your complex answer.

Comment: I searched for related threads to see what the risks are exactly with this approach and unsurprisingly, this turns out to be a workaround about as old as [function volatility categories](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) themselves, which comes with the benefit of being tested and improved along the way: you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384767/5298879) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164081/242866). I subsequently added `parallel safe` to the answer.

Comment: Strange but Postrges in Supabase gives me this error `Failed to run sql query: generation expression is not immutable` for concat_ws_immutable function.

Comment: I noticed that the second block of code in my answer defined the `concat_ws_immutable()` and then still used the regular, non-immutable `concat_ws()` in the generated expression. It's now corrected.

Comment: Not a problem, I have noticed that already @/Zegarek