# NULL-input for concatenated string in generated column

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, concatenation

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS club.climbers 
(
    climber_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    climber_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    climber_last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    climber_full_name TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (climber_first_name || ' ' || climber_last_name) STORED NOT NULL,
    sex_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES club.sex,
    climber_date_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    climber_phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    postal_code_id INTEGER REFERENCES club.postal_codes,
    street VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    building VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    apartment VARCHAR(5),
    full_address TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (street || ',' || building || '-' || apartment) STORED
);
```

But `apartment` can be NULL and then `full_address` would be NULL too. I need to ignore NULL values from `apartment`.

I tried to use `CONCAT` and `COALESCE`, but I don't know how to suppress a dangling '-' when `apartment` is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `CASE` expression:

```
full_address TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
    (street || ',' || case when apartment is not null then building || '-' || apartment 
                           else building end) STORED
```

which - for inserts as

```
insert into climbers (street, building, apartment) values ('Wall street', 'A', '10');
insert into climbers (street, building, apartment) values ('5th Avenue', 'B', null);
```

results in

```
street          building    apartment   full_address
Wall street     A           10          Wall street,A-10
5th Avenue      B           null        5th Avenue,B
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WINkEB9c).

Answer (score 2):

You can include the `-` in the first argument to [coalesce()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) like:

```
full_address TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (street || ',' || building || 
    coalesce('-' || apartment, '')) STORED);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution, I dont have any example to check comprehensively, but I believe it will work.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS club.climbers
(
    climber_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    climber_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    climber_last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    climber_full_name TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (climber_first_name || ' ' || climber_last_name) STORED NOT NULL,
    sex_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES club.sex,
    climber_date_birth DATE NOT NULL,
    climber_phone VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    postal_code_id INTEGER REFERENCES club.postal_codes,
    street VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    building VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    apartment VARCHAR(5),
    full_address TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        street || ',' || building ||
        CASE WHEN apartment IS NOT NULL THEN '-' || apartment ELSE '' END
    ) STORED NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single case with a single column, [Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50552/andomar)'s version seems best. A custom function would be overkill.

#### For repeated use / multiple columns

Optimized expression, with white space and separators (only) where due:

```
immutable_concat_ws(' - ', street || ', ' || building, apartment)
```

`immutable_concat_ws()` is a custom function as explained below.
Basically:

```
concat_ws(' - ', street || ', ' || building, apartment)
```

See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)

**But** generated columns require **`IMMUTABLE`** expressions. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

So create the custom `immutable_concat_ws()` for text input only (guaranteed in your case). Ideally, as **superuser**:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE internal IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'text_concat_ws';
```

See:

- [Create an immutable clone of concat_ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54372666/create-an-immutable-clone-of-concat-ws/54384767#54384767)

Or, without superuser privileges, and as "standard SQL" function (requires Postgres 14+). See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION immutable_concat_ws(text, VARIADIC text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN array_to_string($2, $1);
```