# How to search in array with LIKE operator

Tags: arrays, postgresql, database-design, sequelize.js, string-matching

```
 id |   name   |          ipAddress           
----+----------+-------------------------
  1 | testname | {192.168.1.60,192.168.1.65}
```

I want to search `ipAddress` with `LIKE`. I tried:

```
{'$mac_ip_addresses.ip_address$': { [OP.contains]: [searchItem]}},
```

This one also:

```
{'$mac_ip_addresses.ip_address$': { [OP.Like] : { [OP.any]: [searchItem]}}},
```

The data type of `ipAddress` is `text[]`. I want to search in `ipAddress` with `LIKE`.
`searchItem` contains the IP that need to be searched in the `ipAddress` field so I want to search in array with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know Sequelize but I can answer from postgres side.

There is no short syntax to search for a pattern inside array in PostgreSQL.

If you want to check pattern for each array element individually, then you need to unfold the array using `unnest`:

```
SELECT id, name, ipaddress
FROM testing
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM unnest(ipaddress) AS ip
  WHERE ip LIKE '8.8.8.%'
);
```

If the array is frequently searched this way, it's better to store the data in normalized form.

However, there is a short syntax (plus GIN index support) for for equality based search (see `@>` and other operators [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)).

```
SELECT id, name, ipaddress
FROM testing
WHERE ipaddress @> ARRAY['8.8.8.8'];
```

Comment: What if we want to just check that the first element in each array matches?

Comment: @Hadi, just use `WHERE my_array_field[1] = '8.8.8.8'`

Answer (score 4):

#### What you asked

**`~~`** is the operator used internally to implementing SQL `LIKE`. There is no [commutator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html#id-1.8.3.17.4) for it - no operator that works with left and right operand switched.
That's the one you'd need for your attempt to use the [`ANY` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) with the pattern to the *left*. Related:

You can [create the **operator**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html), though, and it's pretty simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reverse_like (text, text)
  RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
'SELECT $2 LIKE $1';

CREATE OPERATOR <~~ (function = reverse_like, leftarg = text, rightarg = text);
```

Inspired by Jeff Janes' idea here:

- [Match string pattern to any array element](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228262/3684)

Then your query can have the *pattern* to the *left* of the operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mac_ip_addresses
WHERE  '192.168.2%.255' <~~ ANY (ipaddress);
```

Simple, but considerably ***slower*** than the `EXISTS` expression [demonstrated by filiprem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480601/939860).

Then again, either query is excruciatingly slow for **big tables**, since neither can use an **index**. A normalized DB design with a n:1 table holding one IP each would allow that. It would also occupy several times the space on disk. Still, the much cleaner implementation ...

While stuck with your current design, there is still a way: create a trigram GIN index on a text representation of the array and add a redundant, "sargable" predicate to the query additionally. Confused? Here's the recipe:

First, trigram indexes? Read this if you are not familiar:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Neither the cast from `text[]` to `text` nor `array_to_string()` are *immutable*. But we need that for an expression index. Long story short, fake it with an immutable wrapper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_textarr2text(text[]) 
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$SELECT array_to_string($1, ',')$$;

CREATE INDEX iparr_trigram_idx ON iparr
USING gin (f_textarr2text(iparr) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Related answer with the *long story* (and why it's safe):

- [Indexing an array for full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210790/indexing-an-array-for-full-text-search)

Then your query can be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mac_ip_addresses
WHERE  NOT ('192.168.9%.255' <~~ ANY (ipaddress))
AND    f_textarr2text(ipaddress) LIKE '192.168.9%.255';  -- logically redundant
```

The added predicate is logically redundant, but can tap into the power of the trigram index.
***Much* faster** for big tables. Still a bit faster, yet:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mac_ip_addresses
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM unnest(ipaddress) ip WHERE ip LIKE '192.168.9%.255')
AND    f_textarr2text(ipaddress) LIKE '192.168.9%.255';
```

But that's minor now.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3a0cb4a4c7a7d286a55066dca2af2773)*

I addressed the question asked, as I took an interest. Might be of interest to the general public. Most probably not what you *need*, though.

#### What you *need*

> I want to search in `ipAddress` with `LIKE`. `searchItem` contains the IP that need to be searched in the `ipAddress` field so I want to search in array with `LIKE`.

That should probably read:

*"I want to search a given IP address (`searchItem`) in the array `ipAddress`. My first idea is to use `LIKE` ..."*

Well, `LIKE` is for pattern matching. To find *complete* IP addresses in an array, it's the wrong tool. [filiprem's second query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480601/939860) with array operators is the way to go. Probably good enough.

Using the [built-in data type `cidr`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-CIDR) instead of `text` would be better. And the `ip4` data type of the additional [ip4r](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r/blob/master/README.ip4r) module would be much better, yet. All in combination with standard array operators like demonstrated.

Finally, converting IPv4 addresses to `integer` and using that with the additional [inrarray module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) should be stellar - as far as performance is concerned.