# Postegresql pattern matching utf8

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pattern-matching

In my mysql database I have a city name in utf-8: "Bucureşti"

And if I do

```
SELECT * 
FROM cities 
WHERE name LIKE 'Bucuresti';  <- without diacritic 'ş' it works in MySQL.
```

How can I achieve this in postgresql also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout out the `unaccent` extension, which is part of the contrib package.