# PostgreSQL: How to create a pairing function?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, plpgsql, sql-function

How do I create a [user defined function in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc.html) that acts like the C function `pair` defined below?

Also, which type of function should I use and why?

(A) [query language (SQL) function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html)
(B) [procedural language function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-pl.html)
(C) [internal function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-internal.html)
(D) [C-language function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-c.html)
(E) [None of the above](http://youtu.be/H0ol9l1P-_A)

Bonus points for implementations in both SQL & PL/pgSQL languages.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int pair(int x, int y)
{
    int z;
    if (x < y) {
        z = x * (y-1);
        y = y - x - 2;
    } else {
        z = (x-1) * y;
        y = x - y - 2;
    }
    return z + pow(y, 2) / 4;
}

// TESTING

void test(int x, int y, int z)
{
    printf("%s", pair(x, y) == z ? "." : "F");
}

int main(void)
{
    test(1, 2, 1);
    test(1, 3, 2);
    test(1, 4, 3);
    test(1, 5, 5);
    test(1, 6, 7);
    test(1, 7, 10);
    test(1, 8, 13);
    test(1, 9, 17);

    test(2, 3, 4);
    test(2, 4, 6);
    test(2, 5, 8);
    test(2, 6, 11);
    test(2, 7, 14);
    test(2, 8, 18);
    test(2, 9, 22);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an SQL [**`CASE`** statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE):

```
CASE WHEN x < y THEN
   x * (y - 1) + ((y - x - 2)^2)::int / 4
ELSE
   (x - 1) * y + ((x - y - 2)^2)::int / 4
END
```

The operator [**`^`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) as well as the function [**`power()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) return `double precision`. So I cast to `int` to match your question.

Wrapped into a plain [**SQL function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) (with operator `^`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pair1(x int, y int)
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN x < y THEN
          x * (y - 1) + ((y - x - 2)^2)::int / 4
       ELSE
          (x - 1) * y + ((x - y - 2)^2)::int / 4
       END
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

In Postgres 9.1 or older you have tro reference input columns with positional parameters `$1`, `$2` instead.

The same as [**PL/pgSQL function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) (with function `power()`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pair2(x int, y int)
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN CASE WHEN x < y THEN
          x * (y - 1) + power(y - x - 2, 2)::int / 4
       ELSE
          (x - 1) * y + power(x - y - 2, 2)::int / 4
       END;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

[**SQL Fiddle** demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2b650/1)

I depends, but generally I would use a simple **SQL function**. And don't forget to declare it [**`IMMUTABLE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html). This allows various performance optimizations in bigger queries and using it in functional indexes. Example with more details:
[Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Comment: Thank you so much, Erwin. This answer is Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

SQL is simpler. If x < y it will return the first element of the array else the second

```
create or replace function pair(x int, y int)
returns double precision as $$
select (array[
    x * (y - 1) + power(y - x - 2, 2) / 4,
    (x - 1) * y + power(x - y - 2, 2) / 4
    ])[(not x < y)::int + 1]
;
$$ language sql;

select
    pair(1, 2) = 1,
    pair(1, 3) = 2,
    pair(1, 4) = 3,
    pair(1, 5) = 5,
    pair(1, 6) = 7,
    pair(1, 7) = 10,
    pair(1, 8) = 13,
    pair(1, 9) = 17,
    pair(2, 3) = 4,
    pair(2, 4) = 6,
    pair(2, 5) = 8,
    pair(2, 6) = 11,
    pair(2, 7) = 14,
    pair(2, 8) = 18,
    pair(2, 9) = 22
;
```

A boolean casted to integer yields 1 or 0. As Postgresql array index starts at 1 then 1 is added to the result of the casting.