# Postgres search ASCII against UTF8

Tags: postgresql, psql

I created my database like this:

`CREATE DATABASE MYDATABASE WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE='ro_RO.utf8' TEMPLATE template0;`

And I have a table `county` populated with UTF8 county names

This query returns the result as I expect:

`SELECT * from county WHERE name='Iași';` (note the comma under s, known as [S-comma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-comma))

However, this query returns no result:

`SELECT * from county WHERE name='Iasi';` (note that the comma has disappeared)

How should I create the database such that the second query also works? I'm switching to postgres, but when I was using MySQL, everything worked fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations)

Comment: I began answering this, found that duplicate, and realised I could never possibly match it's explanation or advice. Hope that question helps.

Comment: Ha. When  you were using MySQL you got the wrong results, but you wanted the wrong results, so it worked how you wanted. Funny. `Iaşi` and `Iasi` are not equal, and a database that treats them as such by default is wrong. MySQL doesn't do that, at least not recent versions, unless you configure it to by using an [*accent-insensitive (non-UCA) collation*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-implementations.html) or you're using a non-Unicode multi-byte charset. PostgreSQL, unfortunately, does not support accent-insensitive collations, you'll have to work around it.

Comment: Hey @CraigRinger I think MySQL worked correctly because I was setting collation to ``utf8_general_ci``