# Find rows where text array contains value similar to input

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sql-like, any, unnest

I'm trying to get rows where a column of type `text[]` contains a value similar to some user input.

What I've thought and done so far is to use the `'ANY'` and `'LIKE`' operator like this:

```
select * from someTable where '%someInput%' LIKE ANY(someColum);
```

But it doesn't work. The query returns the same values as that this query:

```
select * from someTable where 'someInput' = ANY(someColum);
```

I've got good a result using the `unnest()` function in a subquery but I need to query this in `WHERE` clause if possible.

**Why** doesn't the `LIKE` operator work with the `ANY` operator and I don't get any errors? I thought that one reason should be that `ANY` operator is in the right-hand of query, but ...

Is there any solution to this without using `unnest()` and if it is possible in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The solution without using `unnest` would be to properly normalize your data model.

Comment: I thought to create a new table instead of a column of this data type if there wasn't any other solution. I'll do it, so! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ANY`  is ***not* an operator** but an SQL construct that can only be used to the *right* of an operator. More:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

The `LIKE` operator - or more precisely: *key word*, that is rewritten with to the `~~` **operator** in Postgres internally - expects the *value* to the left and the *pattern* to the right. There is no [`COMMUTATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html#id-1.8.3.18.6) for this operator (like there is for the simple equality operator `=`) so Postgres cannot flip operands.

Your attempt:

```
select * from someTable where '%someInput%' LIKE ANY(someColum);
```

... has left and right operand backwards. `'%someInput%'` is the *value* and elements of the array column `someColum` are taken to be patterns,  which is not what you want.

It *would* have to be something like *`ANY (someColum) LIKE '%someInput%'`* - but the `ANY` construct is only allowed to the *right* of an operator. You are hitting a road block.

Related:

- [Is there a way to usefully index a text column containing regex patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504758/is-there-a-way-to-usefully-index-a-text-column-containing-regex-patterns/34505673#34505673)
- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

You can normalize your relational design and save *elements* of the array in separate rows in a separate table. Barring that, [**`unnest()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is the solution, as you already found yourself. But while you are only interested in the existence of at least one matching element, an [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) subquery will be most efficient and avoid duplicates in the result. Postgres can stop the search as soon as the first match is found:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT -- SELECT list can be empty for this purpose
    FROM   unnest(someColum) elem
    WHERE  elem LIKE '%someInput%'
  );
```

You may want to escape special characters in `someInput`. See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

**Careful** with the negation (`NOT LIKE ALL (...)`) when `NULL` can be involved:

- [Check if NULL exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848009/check-if-null-exists-in-postgres-array/34848472#34848472)

Comment: Thank you for the info!!

Comment: Dear Erwin, I wonder if adding an index on that `[]text` column makes any sense in this case, and if yes, which type? Thank you!

Comment: @shadyyx That all depends. Basics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860

Comment: Reading your answer and the documentation it appears to me that it makes no sense adding a `GIN` index on an array column, if I need to search for elements using `LIKE 'input%'` in a subquery `unnest`ing the original array. Thank you.

Comment: @shadyyx: That's correct. But there are always other ways ...

Answer (score 10):

An admittedly imperfect possibility might be to use [`ARRAY_TO_STRING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), then use `LIKE` against the result.  For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ARRAY_TO_STRING(someColum, '||') LIKE '%someInput%';
```

***This approach is potentially problematic***, though, because someone could search over two array elements if they discover the joining character sequence.  For example, an array of `{'Hi','Mom'}`, connected with `||` would return a result if the user had entered `i||M` in place of `someInput`.  Instead, the expectation would probably be that there would be no result in that case since neither `Hi` nor `Mom` individually contain the `i||M` sequence of characters.

Answer (score 9):

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176240/postgresql-text-array-substring-search) was marked duplicate and linked to a question out of context by a careless mod. This question comes closest to what I asked so I leave my answer here. (I think it may help people for who `unnest()` would be a solution)

In my case a combination of `DISTINCT` and `unnest()` was the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_) *
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(tags) tag, *
  FROM someTable
  ) x
WHERE (tag like '%someInput%');
```

`unnest(tags)` expands the text array to a list of rows and `DISTINCT ON (id_)` removes the duplicates that result from the expansion, based on a unique `id_` column.

**Update**

Another way to do this without `DISTINCT` within the `WHERE` clause would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable 
WHERE (
  0 < (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM unnest(tags) AS tag
    WHERE tag LIKE '%someInput%'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069718/9033534).

This answer was exactly what I was looking for. It also provides for some useful tips (and examples) in case you need more flexibility.

It basically explains the **ANY()**, the **@>** and the **&&** operators.

*"If you want to search multiple values, you can use @> operator"*

*"@> means contains all the values in that array. If you want to search if the current array contains any values in another array, you can use &&"*