# Postgresql Text Array substring search

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column `tags`, which is of type *text array* `TEXT[]`. I can use the following query to retrieve rows that contain certain tags from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM records  WHERE ('foobar' = ANY (tags));
```

This query retrieves all rows that contain a `foobar` tag. This works fine.

Now, I'm in a situation where I need to search the `tags` arrays for sub-strings. I tried the `LIKE` operator with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM records  WHERE ('%oo%' LIKE ANY (tags));
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I'm using Postgresql `10.3`

Comment: Another duplicate with explanation of why it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657669/postgresql-text-array-contains-value-similar-to

Comment: @JGH This should be the marked duplicate link. I'm glad you posted it, since the one that LaurenzAlbe posted doesn't help me at all...