# Sqlalchemy query LIKE statement on an Array column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am having following model and the column skills is of type VARCHAR[] in the Postgres DB

```
class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = "jobs"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    job_title = Column(String)
    is_remote = Column(String)
    skills = Column(ARRAY(String))
```

I want to return return by filtering skills if it partially matche at least one query string. **LIKE [java, go]**

```
def db_query(db:Session, search: List[str]):
        return db.query(Job) \
            .filter(
            or_(Job.skills.like(any_([search]))))
```

I get following error while executing the method:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction)
 operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ text
LINE 3: WHERE jobs.skills LIKE ANY (ARRAY['java','research'])
                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: I think you can translate [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657669/find-rows-where-text-array-contains-value-similar-to-input) to statement builder

Comment: Why do you use an array? It works, but will be slow by design. A relational database like PostgreSQL works best when using a relational model, like 3NF.