# Effiecient for/each loop to match phrases?

Tags: regex, performance, postgresql, for-loop, database-design

I am going to use a for/each loop, to search different names (`table1`) among textual information of records in another table (`table2`) using regular expressions.

```
SELECT id FROM "table1"
where tags ~* 'south\s?\*?africa'
   or description ~* 'south\s?\*?south'
order by id asc;
```

but I do not know how to put it in a for each loop!

`table1`:

```
 t1ID | NAME
 1    | Shiraz      
 2    | south africa
 3    | Limmatplatz
```

`table2`:

```
t2ID |TAGS                   | DESCRIPTIONS
101  |shiraz;Zurich;river    | It is too hot in Shiraz and Limmatplatz
201  |southafrica;limmatplatz| we went for swimming
```

I have a list of names in `table1`. Another table has some text information that might contain those names.
I would like to get back the id of `table2` that contains items in `table1` with the id of the items.

For example:

```
t2id | t1id
101  |1
101  |3
201  |2
201  |3
```

My tables have 60,000 and 550.000 rows. 
I need to use a way that time wise be efficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. A simple join works.

```
SELECT t2.id AS t2id, t1.id AS t1id
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table1 t2 ON t2.tags        ~* replace(t1.name, ' ', '\s?\*?')
                 OR t2.description ~* replace(t1.name, ' ', '\s?\*?')
ORDER  BY t2.id;
```

But performance will be ***terrible*** for big tables.
There are several things you can do to improve it:

1. Normalize `table2.tags` into a separate 1:n table.
   Or an n:m relationship to a `tag` table if tags are used repeatedly (typical case). Details:

   - [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
2. Use trigram or textsearch indexes

   - [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
3. Use a `LATERAL` join to actually use those indexes.

   - [LATERAL JOIN not using trigram index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267109/lateral-join-not-using-trigram-index/37364422#37364422)
4. Ideally, use the new capability in Postgres **9.6** to search for ***phrases*** with full text search. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html)

> Full-text search can now search for phrases (multiple adjacent words)

Comment: thank you for the reply!
I am new in Postgresql to use the multiple adjacent words!:(

Comment: I wanted to do search in java, but I thought it might be faster in database!

Comment: @Raha1986: Pattern matching is a complex matter. Details of the requirements matter. If done right, your RDBMS (especially Postgres) will execute it *much* faster than any other instance in your tool chain.

Comment: Means the best way is using the new capability of Postgres 9.6!right? is it the most efficient way?

Comment: @Raha1986: Probably yes - in combination with my other advice.