# Can the order of individual operands affect whether a SQL expression is sargable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A colleague of mine who is generally well-versed in SQL told me that the order of operands in a > or = expression could determine whether or not the expression was sargable. In particular, with a query whose case statement included:

```
CASE
when (select count(i.id)
            from inventory i
            inner join orders o on o.idinventory = i.idInventory
            where o.idOrder = @order) > 1 THEN 2
            ELSE 1
```

and was told to reverse the order of the operands to the equivalent

```
CASE
when 1 < (select count(i.id)
            from inventory i
            inner join orders o on o.idinventory = i.idInventory
            where o.idOrder = @order) THEN 2
            ELSE 1
```

for sargability concerns. I found no difference in query plans, though ultimately I made the change for the sake of sticking to team coding standards. Is what my co-worker said true in some cases? Does the order of operands in an expression have potential impact on its execution time? This doesn't mesh with how I understand sargability to work.

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) I would be really surprised in any database.

Comment: In general, I would say "no", the order does not affect the query, since SQL by definition is a declarative language. Well... unless the SQL query optimizer is subpar. MySQL, for example, gets confused sometimes, and produces quite different plans for seemingly identical queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Postgres, the answer is definitely: **"No."** ([[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) was added later.)

The query planner can flip around left and right operands of an operator as long as a  [`COMMUTATOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xoper-optimization.html#id-1.8.3.16.4) is defined, which is the case for all instance of `<` and `>`. (Operators are actually defined by the operator itself and their accepted operands.) And the query planner will do so to make an expression "sargable". Related answer with detailed explanation:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

It's different for other operators without `COMMUTATOR`. Example for `~~` (`LIKE`):

- [LATERAL JOIN not using trigram index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267109/lateral-join-not-using-trigram-index/37364422#37364422)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the most popular modern databases like Microsoft SQL, Oracle, Postgres, MySql, Teradata, the answer is definitely **NO**.

**What is a SARGable query?**

A SARGable query is the one that strive to narrow the number of rows a database has to process in order to return you the expected result. What I mean, for example:

Consider this query:

```
select * from table where column1 <> 'some_value';
```

Obviously, using an index in this case is useless, because a database most certainly would have to look through all rows in a table to give you expected rows.

But what if we change the operator?

```
select * from table where column1 = 'some_value';
```

In this case an index can give good performance and return expected rows almost in a flash.

SARGable operators are: *=, <, >, <= ,>=, LIKE (without %), BETWEEN*
Non-SARGable operators are: *<>, IN, OR*

Now, back to your case.
 
Your problem is simple. You have X and you have Y. X > Y or Y < X - in both cases you have to determine the values of both variables, so this switching gives you nothing.

**P.S.** Of course, I concede, there *could* be databases with very poor optimizers where this kind of swithing could play role. But, as I said before, in modern databases you should not worry about it.