# Rails 4 and PostgreSQL - Query to match a String using LIKE with an Accented String stored in the Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My application have members with fields with accented (spanish) characters. 
Example:

```
m.lastname = "Fernández"
```

I want to find this member using the PostgreSQL LIKE operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE lastname LIKE '%rna%';
```

But, because 'a' and 'á' are different characters, that doesn't work.
Any help on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations

Comment: Thats what I need! Thank you @potashin

Comment: As potashin pointed out, the solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations