# pg_trgm how to give higher similarity score when only accents vary

Tags: postgresql

pg_trgm gives me a score of 0.4 for both of these comparisons :

```
SELECT similarity('Noemie','Noémie');
0.4 

SELECT similarity('Noemie','NoXmie');
0.4
```

Obviously the first one is more "similar" than the second, accents are often ommited in data entry, so it's quite useful to have a score that gives high similarity to letters that vary only by presence of absence of a accent.

Is their a way to tweak pg_trgm to give higher similarity score for words that differ only by accents ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by suggesting that you remove the accents from your character set.  Postgres offers a function to do this, `unaccent()`, but you need to install it separately.  [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html) is information on the topic.

With this function (or a similar function), you could do:

```
SELECT similarity(unaccent('Noemie'), unaccent('Noémie'));
```

Treating the two values the same might be going too far.  A weighted average of the two might be more appropriate:

```
SELECT (alpha * similarity(unaccent('Noemie'), unaccent('Noémie'0)) + 
        (1 - alpha) * similarity('Noemie', 'Noémie')
       )
```

`alpha` would be a value between 0 and 1 that gives the weighting for similarity of accented characters.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations) is a good discussion of this issue.