# Folding case to speed up comparisons

Tags: c#, case-folding

```
"strasse".Equals("STRAße",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

This returns true. Which is correct. Unfortunately, when I store one of these in postgres, it thinks they are not the same when doing a case insensitive match (for example, with `~*`).  I've also tested with citext.

So one solution would be to pre-fold the case, thus storing `strasse` for either of these values, in another column. I could then index and search on that for matches.

I've been looking for how to fold case in C# for a while, and haven't been able to find a solution in C#. Obviously that knowledge is there because it can compare these strings properly, I just can't find where to get it from.

One solution would be to spawn a perl process `perl -E "binmode STDOUT, ':utf8'; binmode STDIN, ':utf8'; while (<>) { print fc }"`, set the C# side of the process to utf8 for those pipes as well, and just send the text through perl to fold the case. But there has to be a better way than that.

Comment: [Related 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249087/335858)

Comment: [Related 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11005036/335858)

Comment: Library [UnidecodeSharp](http://unidecode.codeplex.com/) could be helpful for this.

Comment: Ah the good old curse of different implementation of collation :-)

Comment: What about ```string.Equals(str1,str2,StringComparison.CurrentCulture)``` ?

Comment: @codebender how does that help do this case-insensitive comparison _in postgres_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the sources I eventually found that most of this implementation is in a set of classes called CompareInfo.

You can find these at [github.com/dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization)

That led me to this page that clues in to the inner workings for the .net culture stuff. [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/globalization-icu)

It seems that dotnet is actually relying completely on native libraries for everything except ordinal operations.

I would assume by this that the .Net Framework is probably using NLS from Win32. For that there is the [FoldStringW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-foldstringw) method that looks promising.

For ICU there is documentation for [Case Mappings](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/casemappings#TOC-Case-Folding) and I found the [u_strFoldCase](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#ae514cad63c76897567f1d7535e857852) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is `string.Normalize()`, which takes a `NormalizationForm` parameter. Michael Kaplan [goes into detail](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/01/31/363701.html) on this. He claims it does a better job than `FoldStringW`.

It does not, however, normalize the case to upper or lower, it only folds to the canonical form. I would suggest you just apply `ToUpper` or `ToLower` afterwards.

Comment: The entire original point was to normalise case, although normalising the rest of unicode with combining characters and all that would likely also play a role in matching stuff later.

Comment: When I said "normalize case" I meant specifically to upper or lower case, rather than folding to canonical forms, which was also part of the question.

Comment: ToUpper / ToLower don't work for case-insensitive matches in all languages, that's part of the problem.

Comment: Even after `string.Normalize`?

Comment: Did you try it with the above strings? I just pushed it through net core 3.1, and, unsurprisingly, it doesn't do what is required.