# EF Core throws NullReferenceException while comparing strings with CompareOptions

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a Worker entity with string Name property, and just want to filter all Workers whose Name contains some specific string (from frontend text input).

When I do the filtering with:

```
_context.Workers.Where(w => w.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper()).ToList()
```

it is working but it does not solves some specific diacritics in filter term.

When i try with:

```
var compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
 _context.Workers.Where(w => compareInfo.IndexOf(w.Name, filter, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) > -1).ToList()
```

i get `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

and console `An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'Project.MyDbContext'.`

I've also tried with

`_context.Workers.Where(w => compareInfo.IndexOf((w.Name??""), filter, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) > -1).ToList()`

to perform a null check, but same.

Did anyone have same problem, or maybe idea what could be changed here so I could accompiish searching with diacritics?

Thx!

Comment: You should tackle this kind of issues by using proper database collation. After all, the query is executed as SQL in the database. More precisely: the actual query *should* be executed in the database. Whatever you add to it that's not supported in C# to SQL conversion will cause EF-core to switch to client-side evaluation and all data in `_context.Workers` will be pulled into memory.

Comment: Ok, any proposal how to do that from C#?

Comment: Probably *not* by using EF: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11005036/861716