# Implement smart search by text field in database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, search

Suppose I have a table named `movie` with a field `name`, that is a `VARCHAR` field.

I want to implement a search bar in my website, so that when a user enters a string I can query movies with that name.

My first approach was quite naive:

```sql
select *
from movie
where name like '%user_string%';
```

The limitations are:

1. Special characters. Say the user string is "Lets go", I want it to return the movie with the name "Let's go" even if the apostrophe is missing.
2. Accents. Say the user string is "Pokemon", I want it to return the movie with the name "Pokémon" even if the accent is missing.

My idea was to create an additional `normalized_name` field, that is computed using the `name` field with all special characters and accents stripped. Then the query would become:

```sql
select *
from movie
where normalized_name like '%user_string%';
```

For instance: user searches for `pokemon`, the database query return a movie with the `normalized_name` = `pokemon`, which real name is `Pokémon`. Obviously the user string would be first normalized too - in order to allow searching by the movie real name too.

Now, is this a valid approach? What is the most widely used one - that may also make the search even better? Is there any literature on the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a trigram index on a stripped version of the column:

1. Create the necessary extensions and create an immutable `unaccent` called `f_unaccent` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/4443371) for more information):

   ```sql
   CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
   CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary, text)
   RETURNS text LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
   '$libdir/unaccent', 'unaccent_dict';

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_unaccent(text)
   RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
   $func$
   SELECT public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary 'public.unaccent', $1)
   $func$;
   ```
2. Create the trigram index on the column:

   ```sql
   CREATE INDEX ON movie USING gin (translate(f_unaccent(name), '''', '') gin_trgm_ops);
   ```
3. Now perform the following query:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM movie
   WHERE translate(f_unaccent(name), '''', '') ILIKE translate(f_unaccent('user_string'), '''');
   ```

Comment: just to mention this code works on postgresql not sql

Comment: @Mahdi Sure, that is SQL, albeit not standard conforming. Perhaps you are mixing up the computer language SQL with Microsoft's fork of Sybase.