# Unaccent() function alternative in TEIID

Tags: globalization, teiid, unaccent

We have a need for accent ignoring search in our application for Europian audience.
Does TEIID offer an alternative to the function mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/5398549)?

TEIID doesn't recognize this function:
TEIID30068 The function 'unaccent(text)' is an unknown form. Check that the function name and number of arguments is correct.

For example, when I search for the surname *Malicky*, I want to find the record *Maličký* as well.
I tried to use collate as well, but TEIID doesn't seem to be supporting that either.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function and implement code in Java for this function http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/16.0.x/content/dev/User_Defined_Functions.html

if you are using Teiid Spring Boot, the procedure is little differnt https://github.com/teiid/teiid-spring-boot/tree/master/samples/udf