# How to wrap record_out() function?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create an `IMMUTABLE` wrapper function as discussed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/14731 but it's not clear how to proceed. The above Stackoverflow answer provides the following example:

For example, given:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary, text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
'$libdir/unaccent', 'unaccent_dict';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT public.immutable_unaccent(regdictionary 'public.unaccent', $1)
$func$;
```

I scanned all the libraries in `lib/` and as far as I can tell none of them export functions related to `record_out()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `record_out()` function is an internal built-in function. You can get its definition like this:

```sql
select pg_get_functiondef('record_out'::regproc);

                    pg_get_functiondef
----------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.record_out(record)+
  RETURNS cstring                                        +
  LANGUAGE internal                                      +
  STABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT                            +
 AS $function$record_out$function$                       +
```

*I don't know for what purpose you want the wrapping function. It only remains to warn that such a change may bring unexpected results.*

Comment: I kept the question as-is and post a separate question explaining what I am trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72468749/14731