# How to create a GENERATED column containing the MD5 of multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, md5, immutability, generated-columns

I tried to add the following table in PostgreSQL 14.3:

```
CREATE TABLE client_cache (
    id            BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    request       VARCHAR COMPRESSION lz4 NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH (request) <= 10240),
    request_body  BYTEA COMPRESSION lz4 NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH (request_body) <= 1048576),
    request_hash VARCHAR GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(ROW(request::BYTEA, request_body)::VARCHAR)) STORED
);
```

But Postgres complains:

> ```
> [42P17] ERROR: generation expression is not immutable
> ```

I've seen many answers discussing how to create a `GENERATED` column containing the `MD5` of a single column, but as soon as you add `ROW()` to calculate `MD5` over multiple columns, the expression is no longer immutable.

I can create a `GENERATED` column using `ROW(MD5(A), MD5(B))` but not `MD5(ROW(A, B))`.

What can I do instead to create a single `MD5` value over multiple columns of varying types (as seen above)?

I know that I can create a view or populate a column using a trigger, but I'd really like to stick to a `GENERATED` column if possible.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. There are multiple nested issues. But first, please describe your actual objective. Be precise, details matter. Why `request::BYTEA`? Seems pointless. Do you *need* a 16-byte hash, or is a `bigint` hash (8 bytes) good enough?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `request_body` represents an HTTP request body which may or may not be binary. That's why I opted for `BYTEA`. The real table contains the corresponding HTTP response and body but I omitted it for brevity. The cast is probably useless so you can drop it. As for the hash, I'd like to represent a real MD5 value, so I'd prefer to stick with 16 bytes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter to clarify, the http response columns are not part of the hash or generated column so it shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I just found a solution that works but is not ideal: `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(request || MD5(request_body))) STORED`. It's not ideal because I'm computing two MD5s per column, but at least now the output structure is better defined. Do you know of a way to clean this up further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest an immutable helper function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_request_md5(_request text, _request_body bytea)
  RETURNS uuid
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS 
'SELECT md5(textin(record_out((md5(_request_body), _request))))::uuid';
```

And a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client_cache (
  id           bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, request      text   COMPRESSION lz4 NOT NULL CHECK (length(request) <= 10240)
, request_body bytea  COMPRESSION lz4 NOT NULL CHECK (length(request_body) <= 1048576)
, request_hash uuid   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (f_request_md5(request, request_body)) STORED
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7bd48339b902d5edbdf17c57a50aafac)*

Note the more efficient `uuid` instead of `varchar`. See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)

#### Background

There are two overloaded variants of `md5()` in Postgres 14 (or any supported version):

```sql
test=> SELECT (proargtypes::regtype[])[0], prorettype::regtype, provolatile
test-> FROM   pg_proc
test-> WHERE  proname = 'md5';
 proargtypes | prorettype | provolatile 
-------------+------------+-------------
 bytea       | text       | i
 text        | text       | i
(2 rows)
```

One takes `bytea`, one `text`, both are `IMMUTABLE` and return `text`. So this expression is immutable:

```
ROW(MD5(request), MD5(request_body))
```

But this is not, like you found out the hard way:

```
MD5(ROW(A, B)::varchar)
```

The text representation of a **`record`** is not immutable. There are many reasons. One obvious reason for the case at hand: `bytea` output can be in (default) `hex` format or in the obsolescent `escape` format. A plain

```
SET bytea_output = 'escape';
```

... would break your generated column.

To get an immutable text representation of a `bytea` value, you'd run it through [`encode(request_body, 'hex')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTION-ENCODE). But don't go there. `md5(request_body)` gives us a faster immutable text "representation" for our purpose.

We still can't cast a record. So I created the wrapper function. Be sure to read this related answer for more explanation:

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)

Like discussed in that answer, the new, built-in function `hash_record_extended()` would be ***much*** more efficient for the purpose. So if a `bigint` is good enough, consider this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE client_cache2 (
  id           bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, request      text   COMPRESSION lz4 NOT NULL CHECK (length(request) <= 10240)
, request_body bytea  COMPRESSION lz4 NOT NULL CHECK (length(request_body) <= 1048576)
, request_hash bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (hash_record_extended((request, request_body), 0)) STORED
);
```

*same db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7bd48339b902d5edbdf17c57a50aafac)*

Works out of the box in Postgres 14 or later.

Related:

- [Why am I getting a an error when creating a generated column in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249404/why-am-i-getting-a-an-error-when-creating-a-generated-column-in-postgresql)
- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Comment: Upvoted! Thank you for the excellent explanation of what is going on under the hood. The suggestion of using `uuid` is also a good one. How does this compare to the answer I posted below? To my naïve mind that solution is shorter, does not require a helper function, and is potentially faster since we compute MD5 only once. Although my columns are all `NOT NULL` it would be great to find a solution that represents `NULL` and empty string differently just in case someone else needs it.

Comment: @Gili: Like I explained: the cast to `varchar` is not immutable and can produce a different result in a different session. See: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=685441267d1632c0e2d5643a57dc84cf)* Plus, concatenation is also unsafe, as two different rows might concatenate to the same. Plus also expensive. I expect my function to be faster - besides doing the right thing.

Comment: Excellent, albeit surprising, answer. I agree with you that the cast from `BYTEA` to `VARCHAR`, isn't safe per your examples. The odd thing is that postgres happily accepts my code as IMMUTABLE. Is this a bug on their end? Also, what is the probability of a collision using `hash_record_extended`? I know that for 16-bits of MD5 it's approximately `1.47*10^-29`.

Comment: Here is an even more revealing demo with a `UNIQUE` index broken by this deceiving cast: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e54a72ccb8bc17a048b66398d0ec47d6)*. Is it a bug? Well, it's a grey area. Postgres might be more restrictive on this one, as it's very restrictive with immutability otherwise. Then again, Postgres also trusts user functions *faking* immutability ... and that's mighty useful at times.

Comment: @Gili: *Also, what is the probability of a collision using hash_record_extended?* Like I said: *Be sure to read this related answer for more explanation:* https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684 It addresses your question in-depth.

Comment: Finally an answer that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution!

Postgres doesn't like:

`request_hash VARCHAR GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(ROW(request, request_body)::VARCHAR)) STORED` but

`request_hash VARCHAR GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MD5(request || request_body::VARCHAR)) STORED` works just fine.

Hooray!

Comment: See discussion why I wouldn't advise to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468749/how-to-create-a-generated-column-containing-the-md5-of-multiple-columns/72469657#comment128021122_72469657