# Rails - Regex to remove accent from bank word

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm new to Rails and I'm using Google Translate to post here. I have a doubt.

I have the following scope:
I'm trying to remove the accent from the bank words when performing a search.

In the parameters it already works with parameterize, but how do I query the bank (inside the where) to remove the accent?
I'm using postgresql.

Initially I tried to use regex_replace, but apparently it didn't work, could I be applying it wrong?

```
   scope :filter_occupation, -> (params) {
     params[:occupation].present? ?
       where("lower(regexp_replace(occupation, '[^\w]+','')) LIKE ?",
       # where("lower(occupation) LIKE ?",
         "%#{params[:occupation].parameterize(separator: ' ')}%")
     :
     all
   }
```

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS, it's considered yelling and it's *especially* annoying in the title.

Comment: This appears to be a SQL problem, too. Postgres?

Comment: sorry I did not know. I adjusted.
Yes (postgresql)

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations).