# I want to get data in Postqresql turkish and english characters, like SQL Server collation

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, collation

In Postqresql, I have this query:

```
select *  
from students 
where name like '%Huseyin%'
```

When I run it, I want to get data that has name is "Huseyin", "Hüseyin", "Huseyın", "Hüseyin".

How can I do this? I use Dapper. I did not create database with collation. I just want to use collation in select query (Turkish special characters is i,ü,ş,ö,ğ)

Comment: try this post and see if you can get it working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations

Comment: PostGreSQL as very poor collations features compare to Microsoft SQL Server. Perhaps you can try to add ICU collations, buts it's bugged with the LIKE operator...

Answer (score 0):

We solved this question like this;

SELECT *
FROM   student
WHERE  unaccent(first_name) ilike unaccent('%caglar%')

it brings data if caglar or çağlar exist in database. Before use "unaccent", it is necessary some setting in postgresql database.

Answer (score -1):

### Add this query and try again.

Select * From [TableName] Where [ColumnName] Like ‘%Ayşe%’ COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS