# Accent insensitive search with accent sensitive sorting in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, localization, full-text-search

In PostgreSQL 12+ it's possible to use nondeterministic ICU collations in order to implement accent insensitive search
([see this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)).

I want to implement **accent insensitive search**, while still using **accent sensitive sorting**.

---

##### Consider the following example:

I have a table named country_region with a single column: "symbol". It stores the following values:

- lubuskie
- łódzkie
- małopolskie

The values have been listed in the expected order, as the Polish alphabet order is L -> Ł -> M.

The below SQL query should return the "łódzkie" field, ignoring the diacritics:

```sql
SELECT * FROM country_region WHERE symbol = 'lodzkie'
```

The below SQL query should return the values ordered per the alphabet (lubuskie -> łódzkie -> małopolskie):

```sql
SELECT * FROM country_region ORDER BY symbol
```

---

##### What I have tried

I have tried using 2 different ICU locales.

In the below collation Unicode locale search works as expected, but rows are sorted in the wrong order:

```sql
CREATE COLLATION ignore_accent (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level1-kc-true', deterministic = FALSE);
CREATE INDEX test_index ON country_region(symbol COLLATE ignore_accent);
```

In the below collation Polish locale sorting works as expected, but diacritics aren't ignored in search:

```sql
CREATE COLLATION ignore_accent (provider = icu, locale = 'pl-u-ks-level1-kc-true', deterministic = FALSE);
CREATE INDEX test_index ON country_region(symbol COLLATE ignore_accent);
```

---

Is it possible to solve this with PostgreSQL? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that that is an ICU bug in the definition of the Polish collation. A web search in their bug database turned up [this](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-7086), which links to [that](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-2298), which seems to be open, but I am not certain whether that is the problem you encounter or not.

As a workaround, you could define the column using the normal, deterministic collation `"pl-PL-x-icu"` and be explicit about the collation in equality comparisons:

```
CREATE COLLATION ignore_accent (
   provider = icu,
   locale = 'und-u-ks-level1-kc-true',
   deterministic = FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX test_index ON country_region(symbol COLLATE ignore_accent);

SELECT * FROM country_region WHERE symbol COLLATE ignore_accent = 'lodzkie';
```

For all other purposes, the normal collation will do.