# Rails 4 pgsql add_index with type GIN or GiST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails it is possible to do:

`add_index :table, :column_name, :using => 'btree'`

Is it possible in Rails 4 with PGSQL to add a `GIN` or `GiST` index like:

`add_index :students, :name, :using => 'gin'`

Or do I have use manual execute statements? The notion behind this is I would like to keep schema.rb instead of using structure.sql

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In Rails 4, you can now do something like this in a migration:

```
add_index :products, :data, using: :gin
```

Comment: Is there any docs on this? I saw a similar answer on Stackoverflow, but `add_index :products, :data, using: :gin` raises an exception when used in a migration.

Comment: check code - it simple sql request [add_index](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index)

Comment: This raises an error `PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gin"` ... and this is on Rails 4.2.

Comment: I had the same error, got it working this command in my migration: `execute("CREATE INDEX some_name ON products USING gin(to_tsvector('data'))")`

Comment: Small correction, you also need to give a configuration as attribute, e. g. 'english': `execute("CREATE INDEX some_name ON products USING gin(to_tsvector('english', 'data'))")`

Comment: Here a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676731/not-able-to-set-special-index-type-options-lower-unaccent-etc-for-gin-and-gi

Comment: Note that `'gin'` as a string like in the question, also works.

Comment: Gin indexes only work on array fields. Change the table definition first

Comment: @King'oriMaina In Rails 5 you can use the `opclass ` argument to use a default operator class and avoid that error: `add_index :products, :data, using: :gin, opclass: :gin_trgm_ops` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index

Comment: Add `enable_extension "btree_gin"`  in the migration above this step.

Comment: @HaseebA btree_gin is not the same thing as trigram indexing, and is relatively useless for string matching in my experience. Scott Bartell has the correct idea to set an operator. If your version does not support an operator, you will need to use SQL

Answer (score 35):

Wow! I had a few hairs turn gray on this one. I am using rails 4.2 and trying to run this migration and it was giving me the same error as people above.

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: data type character varying has no default
```

I found out that you can in fact still continue to use schema.rb and do not have to use the config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

The one major thing I was missing was installing postgres contrib modules. I made the assumption that features like gin and gist were already turned on. I never noticed but modules are shown in your schema.rb file. They appear at the top like this

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151203234708) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "pg_trgm"
  enable_extension "fuzzystrmatch"
  enable_extension "btree_gin"
  enable_extension "btree_gist"
```

if you do not see btree_gin enabled, you can not use the code

```
add_index :products, :data, using: :gin
```

you can install any module by running a migration like so. The changes will be reflected in your schema.rb

```
class InstallSomeContribPackages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gin;"
    execute "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;"
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS btree_gin;"
    execute "DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS btree_gist;"
  end
end
```

here is a list of [postgres modules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib.html)

Comment: You can also add extensions in migrations with migration syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611226/how-to-install-postgres-extensions-at-database-creation `enable_extension "btree_gin"`

Comment: And I would also note, that `btree_gin` is enough, at least for PostgreSQL 9.4