# Search for non-English titled movies via Rotten Tomatoes API. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, httparty, rotten-tomatoes

I have the following function to search for movie via [Rotten Tomatoes API](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/iodocs) by its title, which may accidentally be spelled not in basic English. I use [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to wrap the API.

```
def self.search_by_title(title)
    options = {query: {apikey: "secret", page_limit: "1" }}
    response = self.get("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=#{CGI.escape(title)}", options)

    movie = JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

So if I make, let's say, the following request (search for "Rashômon" movie):

```
http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=#{CGI.escape(Rashômon)}&apikey=apikey
```

it returns empty hash

```
{"total"=>0, "movies"=>[], "links"=>{"self"=>"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=Rash%C3%83%C2%B4mon&page_limit=1&page=1"}
```

If I instead use just "Rashomon" it is OK. But I obtain these titles via 3d party API and sometimes it gives titles in such format.

I know that I should probably search by other identifications (imdb_id, english name etc., but sometimes I cannot provide these variables and use search_by_title as a fallback function.

Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Could this answer help you in some way?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522715/removing-accents-diacritics-from-string-while-preserving-other-special-chars-tr

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much! You can post it as answer

Comment: You're welcome! I tried but it was auto-converted to a comment because it was too simple. Just give the comment an upvote instead ;-)