# Replace umlaute (äüö) for SEO link in rails - best way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, seo, replace

I'm using the permalink_fu plugin to create permalinks from titles. My problem is: If the title contains german characters, they are just replaced with '_'.

What I need is something that replaces
ä with ae
ü with ue
ö with oe

I fount String.tr but the problem here is that it replaces 1 character with 1 replacement, so it would work for replacing

é with e
ø with o

etc.

Does anyone have a nice and clean solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You seem to want to replace only select characters, not all.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? 1.8 was barely Unicode aware. 1.9.2 is much, much, better and provides some good code-set translation tools which are aware of multi-byte characters, instead of being tied to bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`String.gsub()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000756):

```
"ich bin doch nicht blöd, mann!".gsub(/[äöü]/) do |match|
    case match
        when "ä"
          'ae'
        when "ö"
          'oe'
        when "ü"
          'ue'
    end
end
```

Of course, the lookup can be improved by using a lookup table, but the principle should be clear.

Comment: When I do this, I get `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)`

Comment: @moose: then you need to fix the locale (specifically LC_CTYPE) under which you are running ruby to be UTF-8. Ruby's locale handling is a cess pit.

Answer (score 17):

Look at transliterate and parameterize (with transliterations in locales/de.yml):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate

```
I18n.transliterate("Über der Höhenstraße")
 => "Ueber der Hoehenstrasse"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize

```
"Über der Höhenstraße".parameterize
 => "ueber-der-hoehenstrasse"
```

If you don't want to write the transliterations yourself, you can install the `rails-i18n` gem.

Answer (score 9):

I have written a small Library called [Asciify](http://github.com/levinalex/asciify/) for exactly that purpose

```
$ sudo gem install asciify
```

Usage:

```
#!/bin/ruby
require "asciify"

"Lücke".asciify   #=> "Luecke"
```

You can provide a YAML-file for custom mappings like so:

```
translator = Asciify.new("/path/to/mappings.yaml")
output_string = translator.convert("input string")
```

(see [the builtin default mapping](http://github.com/levinalex/asciify/blob/master/lib/mappings/default.yaml) for the expected format)

The whole project is quite old, but maybe it does the job you need it to.  If not, maybe the [source code](http://github.com/levinalex/asciify/blob/6f1e67fd508fedf0288ca97fe7b2a2b7acbfca9f/lib/asciify.rb) will be helpful.

Comment: Nice. I just posted a PR to it to make it a little easier to use.

Answer (score 6):

```
"äöü".gsub('ä','ae').gsub('ö','oe').gsub('ü','ue')
```

;)

Comment: but then again downvote because multiple `sub!`s don't work in ruby1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try [String.sub!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000801).

Answer (score 0):

[I asked a similar question once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/javascript-equivalent-of-xpaths-translate). It was for JavaScript, and it takes a regex based aproach. Maybe the solution still carries some value for you, methodologically speaking.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this: `"Ich bin doch nicht böld ähhh ühh öhhh".gsub(/[äöüßÄÖÜ„“§%&–+]/){|t|t.to_xs}`

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `to_xs' for "ö":String