# Why doesn't this Unicode gsub substitution work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878789/replace-umlaute-auo-for-seo-link-in-rails-best-way) it was asked how to replace Umlaute. The accepted question was the following code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
foo = "ich bin doch nicht blöd, mann!".gsub(/[äöü]/) do |match|
    case match
        when "ä" 'ae'
        when "ö" 'oe'
        when "ü" 'ue'
    end
end
puts foo
```

However, when I try to run this, the output is:

```
$ ruby /tmp/test.rb 
ich bin doch nicht bld, mann!
```

So the Umlaute obviously don't get replaced. **Is there something I am missing?** I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"ich bin doch nicht blöd, mann!".gsub("ä","ae").gsub("ö","oe").gsub("ü","ue")
```

Should do the trick

Comment: That was fast and works. Thanks! Any idea why the other code won't work? 

(I will accept your answer in 10 minutes, since this is the minimum time to wait before accepting)

Comment: This gets ugly real quick (think Ä, ä, Ö, ö, Ü, ü and ß; é è etc.)

Answer (score 7):

You are using incorrect syntax, you either need to use `then` or a newline and indentation.

```
# encoding: utf-8
foo = "ich bin doch nicht blöd, mann!".gsub(/[äöü]/) do |match|
    case match
        when "ä" then 'ae'
        when "ö" then 'oe'
        when "ü" then 'ue'
    end
end

puts foo
```

or

```
# encoding: utf-8
foo = "ich bin doch nicht blöd, mann!".gsub(/[äöü]/) do |match|
    case match
        when "ä"
            "ae"
        when "ö"
            "oe"
        when "ü"
            "ue"
    end
end
```

The robust way to do this would be `result = Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', foo)` but you need to set locale to `"de_DE"` which cannot be done in ruby without a c extension.

Comment: Its interesting ruby doesn't throw a warning for missing then statements! +1

Comment: @cggaurav Usually leaving out the `then` would be a syntax error, but writing two string literals next to each other is actually syntactically valid. Writing `"ä" 'ae'` is the same as writing `"äae"`. That's a syntactic oddity that Ruby inherited from C.

Comment: I read discussions on Ruby core developers site about deprecating this feature when the two literals are on the same line. It seems to be the consensus that it is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

(Not a real answer to the question, but a bit large for a comment.) `gsub` has syntax for this kind of substitution, using a Hash:

```
#encoding: utf-8
table = {"ä" => 'ae',
         "ö" => 'oe',
         "ü" => 'ue'}
re = Regexp.union(table.keys)
# re = /[äöü]/ # is fine too
p "ich bin doch nicht blöd, mann!".gsub(re, table)
# => "ich bin doch nicht bloed, mann!"
```

Comment: I have seen this mentioned thrice recently. Twice by you, and once by me.

Comment: I have a secret agenda :), I want the Regexp.union thing to be automatic, leaving the syntax `gsub(hash)`. But the feature is not well known at the moment.

Comment: I agree. I felt the same thing.