# How to convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 a webpage in java/groovy

Tags: java, groovy, character-encoding

I want to read a webpage A in ISO-8859-1 charset, according to the browser, and return the content in UTF-8 as a content of the webpage B.

This is: I want to show the content of the page A in the same charset that I use to show the rest of the page B, that is UTF-8.

How do I do this in java/groovy?

thanks in advance

Comment: seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466184/convert-ansi-characters-to-utf-8-in-java and possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655891/converting-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-in-java-how-to-keep-it-as-single-byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Groovy you could write something like this:

```
def source = new URL("http://www.google.com").getText("ISO-8859-1")
def target = new String(source.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: I don't get the 2nd line. According to the Groovy API, `source` will be a (UTF-16) `java.lang.String`. You convert it from a string to a UTF-8 encoded byte array and back to a (UTF-16 encoded) string again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what stack you're building on or how you're accessing the content, but the general mechanism for such a transcoding operation is to use UTF-16 as an intermediary; that is, convert ISO-8859-1 bytes to UTF-16 chars to UTF-8 bytes.

You could use [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) (with the an ISO-8859-1 [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)), then write bytes via [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) (with a UTF-8 `Charset`).

Some APIs provide encoding operations as part of their I/O classes (e.g. [`ServletResponse.getWriter()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17410_01/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter())).

*I'm ignoring any need to parse and transform the data, which is a whole other can of worms.*