# Transliteration in ruby

Tags: ruby, transliteration

What is the simplest way for transliteration of non English characters in ruby. That is conversion such as:

`translit "Gévry"`
`#=> "Gevry"`

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of my earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby has an [Iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html) library in its stdlib which converts encodings in a very similar way to the usual `iconv` command

Comment: Yeah.. `Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', string).to_s` does the job.

Comment: I just tried this on the OP's example, and it returned "Gvry", not "Gevry".

Comment: @jrdioko It should be `Iconv.iconv('ascii//translit//ignore', 'utf-8', string)`

Comment: You need to use the `Iconv.conv` method instead of `Iconv.iconv` for this.

Comment: Iconv.iconv will be deprecated, how do you do this transliteration using String#encode instead?

Answer (score 8):

Use the **UnicodeUtils** gem. This works in 1.9 and 2.0. Iconv has been deprecated in these releases.

```
gem install unicode_utils
```

Then try this in IRB:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > require 'unicode_utils'  #=> true
2.0.0p0 :002 > r = "Résumé"             #=> "Résumé"
2.0.0p0 :003 > r.encoding               #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
2.0.0p0 :004 > UnicodeUtils.nfkd(r).gsub(/(\p{Letter})\p{Mark}+/,'\\1')
                                        #=> "Resume"
```

Now an explanation of how this works!

First you have to normalize the string in [NFKD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) (Normalization Form (K)ompatability Decomposition) format. The "é" unicode codepoint, known as "[latin small letter e with acute](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm)", can be represented in two ways:

- é = U+00E9
- é = (e = U+0065) + (acute = U+0301)

With the first form being the most popular as a single code point. The second form is the decomposed format, separating the grapheme (what appears as "é" on your screen) into its two base code points, the ASCII "e" and the acute accent mark. Unicode can compose a grapheme from many code points, which is useful in some Asian writing systems.

Note you typically want to normalize your data in a standard format for comparison, sorting, etc. In ruby the two formats of "é" here are NOT equal(). In IRB, do this:

```
> "\u00e9"                   #=> "é"
> "\u0065\u0301"             #=> "é"
> "\u00e9" == "\u0065\u0301" #=> false
> "\u00e9" > "\u0065\u0301"  #=> true
> "\u00e9" >= "f"            #=> true  (composed é > f)
> "\u0065\u0301" > "f"       #=> false (decomposed é < f)

> "Résumé".chars.count       #=> 6
> decomposed = UnicodeUtils.nfkd("Résumé")  
                             #=> "Résumé"
> decomposed.chars.count     #=> 8
> decomposed.length          #=> 6
> decomposed.gsub(/(\p{Letter})\p{Mark}+/,'\\1')
                             #=> "Resume"
```

Now that we have the string in NFKD format, we can apply a regular expression using the "property name" syntax (\p{property_name}) to match a letter followed by one or more diacritic "marks". By capturing the matching letter, we can use gsub to replace the letter+diacritics by the captured letter throughout the string.

This technique removed diacritic marks from ASCII letters and will not transliterate character sets such as Greek or Cyrillic strings into equivalent ASCII letters.

Comment: +1 for the ingenious way of separating letter accents and then removing them. -1 for not normalizing 'ı' as 'i'

Answer (score 3):

Try taking a look at [this script](http://www.techniconseils.ca/en/scripts-remove-accents-ruby.php) from TechniConseils which replaces accented characters in a string. Example of usage:

```
"Gévry".removeaccents #=> Gevry
```