# Whats the easiest way to replace all non ASCII characters with their ASCII equivalents in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transliteration in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726404/transliteration-in-ruby)

I am searching for a simple way to convert strings like these:

- "spaß" to "spass"
- "über" to "ueber"
- etc.

This is needed for generating valid usernames from names of people.

Comment: German only? What do you want to do with something like _crêpes_ where the `ê` means that the origin of the word was _crespes_? What about _naïveté_, or _ça va_? According to another site, _"Georg Friedrich Händel is simplified into "Haendel" by the Germans and into "Handel" by the English (the latter is the spelling he used himself when he moved to London)."_ So how do you know which to pick?

Comment: Duplicate of [Transliteration in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726404/transliteration-in-ruby) and [Transliteration  with Iconv in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410340/transliteration-with-iconv-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called transliteration. An approximation of this (see examples) can be performed using the [Iconv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html#method-i-iconv) class.

Try one of the following (require 'iconv' first):

```
Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', string).to_s
Iconv.iconv('ascii//translit', 'utf-8', string).to_s

irb(main):013:0> Iconv.iconv('ascii//translit', 'utf-8', 'spaß').to_s
=> "spass"
irb(main):014:0> Iconv.iconv('ascii//translit', 'utf-8', 'crêpes').to_s
=> "crepes"
irb(main):017:0> Iconv.iconv('ascii//translit', 'utf-8', 'über').to_s
=> "uber"
```

There's also an `iconv` command line utility. More information on that and some Ruby examples (search for 'ruby') [here](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/encoding_conversion_with_iconv).

An alternative to this is [Unidecode](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/Iconv.html#method-i-iconv), which I guess was inspired by the original Perl implementation. I haven't used it in its Ruby incarnation, but it should do multi-char expansions (which apparently you want) better.

Finally, if you're running Rails, you may find [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/e1831f7079eb38f7) interesting. It details some differences between alternative approaches to transliteration, and shows a way to do this within the Rails core (`ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate`)

Comment: +1 Good answer; I didn't know of the term "transliteration" before, so thanks! Interesting to see that the conversion of über does not match the OP's desired outcome. Is the OP wrong to want to throw an `e` in, or is the transliteration library too language-agnostic?

Comment: I think it's too language-agnostic. The Unidecode distribution comes with pretty extensive data files detailing better multi-char transliterations, at least in principle.