# How to remove Latin characters like accents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to remove Latin characters like accents or `"ñ"` in Ruby. I tried using `force_encoding('UTF-8')` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: What about non-Latin characters?

Comment: Do you actually want to convert them to their non-accented ASCII equivalent?

Comment: Duplicate of [Transliteration in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726404/transliteration-in-ruby) or [Transliteration with Iconv in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410340/transliteration-with-iconv-in-ruby) or [How Do I Replace Accented Latin Characters in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby).

Comment: Exactly i need to convert é to e and ñ to n ! The best solution is use gsub an not forcing to explicit encode ?

Answer (score 5):

This piece of code I used in other answers about Ruby encoding proved to be effective most of the time. Make sure your script itself is saved with UTF8 coding:

```
t="doña"
p t.force_encoding(Encoding.locale_charmap).encode('UTF-8')
#=>"do\u251C\u2592a"
```

If it is replace you want instead of encode there are libraries for that but you could also use a simple regular expression

```
t="déjà"
puts t.gsub(/[éèàùµñçêï]/, '?') => d?j?
```

EDIT: i noticed in the comments you want to replace the special version of a character by the normal one, you can do this like follows

```
p string_with_special_chars.tr( 
"ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåĀāĂăĄąÇçĆćĈĉĊċČčÐðĎďĐđÈÉÊËèéêëĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħÌÍÎÏìíîïĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłÑñŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøŌōŎŏŐőŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšſŢţŤťŦŧÙÚÛÜùúûüŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵÝýÿŶŷŸŹźŻżŽž", 
"AAAAAAaaaaaaAaAaAaCcCcCcCcCcDdDdDdEEEEeeeeEeEeEeEeEeGgGgGgGgHhHhIIIIiiiiIiIiIiIiIiJjKkkLlLlLlLlLlNnNnNnNnnNnOOOOOOooooooOoOoOoRrRrRrSsSsSsSssTtTtTtUUUUuuuuUuUuUuUuUuUuWwYyyYyYZzZzZz")
```