# Ruby character transliteration

Tags: ruby, transliteration

What's the current best way to transliterate characters to 7-bit ASCII in Ruby? Most of questions I've seen on SO are 3 or 4 years old and the solutions don't fully work.

I want a method that will work for a wide range of Latin alphabets and, for example, convert

> Your résumé’s a non–encyclopædia

to

> Your resume's a non-encyclopaedia

but I cannot find a way that does that, particularly for folding 8-bit ASCII to 7-bit ASCII.

```ruby
s =  "Your r\u00e9sum\u00e9\u2019s a non\u2013encyclop\u00e6dia"
puts Iconv.iconv('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8', s)
# => Your r'esum'e's a non-encyclopaedia
puts s.encode('ascii//ignore//translit', 'utf-8')
# => Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (UTF-8 to ascii//ignore//translit)
puts s.encode('ascii', 'utf-8')
# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00E9 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII
puts s.encode('ascii', 'utf-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
# Your r?sum??s a non?encyclop?dia
puts I18n.transliterate(s)
# Your resume?s a non?encyclopaedia
```

Since `Iconv` is deprecated I'd rather not use that if I don't have to, but I'd do it if that is the only thing that works.   Obviously I could put in custom 8-bit ASCII to 7-bit ASCII translations, but I'd prefer to use a supported solution that has been thoroughly tested.

The translation is handled fine by [International Components for Unicode](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit) with its Latin-ASCII translation, but that is only available for Java and C.

### UPDATE

What I ended up doing was writing my own character translation routines to take care of punctuation and whitespace, after which I could use `I18n.transliterate` to do the rest. I'd still prefer finding and using a well-maintained library function to handle the stuff `I18n` does not.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to add a somewhat heavy dependency (unless your already on Rails), ActiveSupport has support (pun not intended) for this:

```
ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars.new("Your r\u00e9sum\u00e9\u2019s not an encyclop\u00e6dia").mb_chars.normalize(:kd).chars.to_a.delete_if {|c| !c.ascii_only?}.join('')
```

This works for all of the letters. It doesn't handle the apostrophe right yet though.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2 but this doesn't work at all: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'delete_if' for #<Enumerator: "Your résumé’s not an encyclopædia":chars>`. I suspect even if it's a syntax error that could be fixed up, all it will do is delete non-ASCII characters.  What I want is to replace them with reasonable substitutes given that the input in basically English.  Note also that I enhanced my example to include an en dash.

Comment: @OldPro: Honestly, your requirements are getting so tight I doubt any library could ever fufil them. And this solution does deal with the letters. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this deletes not only the punctuation but also the 'æ', which is not good enough for this project.

Comment: @OldPro: Glad to try ;). I hope you find something, but in the meantime I suggest you look at working with the original UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the [removeaccents script](http://www.techniconseils.ca/en/scripts-remove-accents-ruby.php) is just right what your want.

Maybe [UnicodeUtils gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179878/632916) can be useful, but only to remove the accents (not to convert things like `æ` AFAIK).

Comment: I'd much prefer to use the standard `I18n.transliterate` over the `removeaccents` script as I'm sure the former is more robust. The only problem with `I18n.transliterate` is that it only handles letters (and numbers?) and does not do anything to normalize punctuation. `removeaccents` has the same limitation.

Comment: @OldPro, I guess you made a good choice. Thank you for commenting it!

Answer (score 1):

Works with any locale:

```rb
  def normalized_text
    I18n.transliterate(text.downcase.strip)
  end
```

Comment: Does not preserve case or whitespace, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do `I18n.transliterate(text)`?