# Translit equivalent in Ruby 2 (without iconv)

Tags: ruby

As we know we can use `Iconv` in Ruby 1.9.3 with `TRANSLIT` flag which will replace accented characters with their ASCII equivalents, **only if they're not present in destination encoding**.

Example of use:

```
require 'iconv'
z = "Håkan"
Iconv.conv("windows-1250//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8", z) 
# => outputs "Hakan" (with diactric removed)
pl = "zażółć"
Iconv.conv("windows-1250//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8", pl)
# => outputs "zażółć" (because windows-1250 contains all this characters)
# well, to be honest it outputs "za\xBF\xF3\xB3\xE6" because of terminal settings
# but I hope you understand
```

However `Iconv` is deprecated and it's recommended to use `String#encode` instead.

However when using `#encode` the problem arises:

```
z.encode('windows-1250', 'utf-8')
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+00E5 to WINDOWS-1250 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1250
```

Is there any way to get behavior similar to one with `iconv` `TRANSLIT` flag using `String#encode` instead in Ruby 2+?

Comment: hm, your example gives me `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'` in Ruby 1.9.3-p448

Comment: You've identified there's a difference between the two methods but haven't shared what the difference is.  What's the desired output of your conversion?

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov - I've made example simpler, maybe now it will be ok.

Comment: @Anthony - I've added information about desired result (and difference)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transliteration in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726404/transliteration-in-ruby)

Comment: @SztupY not duplicate, this question is about using `String#encode`, that question sticks with `iconv` or external gems...

Comment: Not a complete equivalent, but you can use this to remove accents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726404/transliteration-in-ruby/16179878#16179878

Comment: @Esse: the question is about how to do something that is deprecated in ruby 2.0. If you can only do it via external gems, or workarounds (as iconv has it's own logic to do transliteration, so not using iconv means you have to do the logic somewhere else), then that's the answer.

Comment: @SztupY: I've added some clarification to question (which actually makes  `UnicodeUtils` pretty useless to me)

Answer (score -1):

If you know what to expect, then you can specify the replacements in a hash:

```
z = "Håkan"
p z.encode('windows-1250', 'utf-8', fallback: {"å"=>"a"}) # => Hakan
```

Comment: Unfortunately it depends - both on input and on destination encoding, so it isn't acceptable solution :(