# using LOWER with IN condition

Tags: postgresql

assume I have a table named `comodity_group` and the structure looks like:

```
+----------+-------+
| group_id | name  |
+----------+-------+
| 1        | Data1 |
+----------+-------+
| 2        | Data2 |
+----------+-------+
| 3        | data3 |
+----------+-------+
```

and I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM comodity_group WHERE name IN('data1','data2','data3')
```

the query return 0 result, because condition is all in lowercase **(note that the condition is also dynamic, meaning it can be Data1 or daTa1, etc)**

so I want to make both condition and field name in lowercase, in other word case insensitive.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ILIKE` and an array:

```
select *
from comodity_group
where name ilike any (array['Data1', 'data2', 'dATA3']);
```

Note that this won't be really fast as the ILIKE operator can't make use of a regular index on the `name` column.

Comment: It also works when you want to look for a value in a set of columns.
Example:

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'avalue' ilike any (array[table_column1, table_column2,...]):

Comment: This is what I needed but also has to add the percent sign before and after each element, for my case. so i had: select *
from comodity_group
where name ilike any (array['%Data1%', '%data2%', '%dATA3%']);

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your name data to lowercase

```
SELECT * FROM comodity_group WHERE lower(name) IN('data1','data2','data3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have control over the terms which appear in the `IN` clause of your query, then you should only need to lowercase the `name` column before making the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM commodity_group
WHERE LOWER(name) IN ('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
```

Off the top of my head, you could also join to an inline table containing the search terms:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'daTa1' AS name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Data2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'datA3'
)
SELECT *
FROM commodity_group t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON LOWER(t1.name) = LOWER(t2.name)
```

With the possible matches in an actual table, we now have the ability to lowercase both sides of the comparison.

Comment: the condition alone can be dynamic like `IN('daTa1','Data2','datA3')`. I can't control the terms in the `IN` clause.

Comment: Are you using dynamic SQL?  Update your question to make this clear.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it's already in the question "*note that the condition is also dynamic, meaning it can be Data1 or daTa1, etc)*"