# How to do username case insensitive in login form?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, symfony4

I'm using the login form from Symfony, but I can't login, if the entered  username is 'FOO' and in the DB is stored 'foo'. I'm using Postgres. It means the username-field is case sensitive. 
What can I do?

Comment: If you are in control over what column type is used, maybe you can solve it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482278/10955263

Comment: @olek07 I think in your case you need to update your UserProvider, check https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html, think about updating `loadUserByUsername()` method to remove the sensitive check for your username value

Comment: Yes, It works. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 5):

This depends mainly on your Database-Server. MySQL is case insensitive,  PostgreSQL is case sensitive.

But you can write query Like this

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('user')
            ->where('LOWER(user.username) = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', strtolower($username))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
```

Comment: Yes, that's also my solution.

Comment: And `property: email` should be deleted from security.yml

Comment: Better to store users with noramlized (lower, etc..) usernames to rid of `LOWER` function and reduce DB load. Look how it is made in FOSUserBundle.

Comment: You are right, but users often enter their email-address like Otto.Mustermann@Gmail.com