# How to make Username Email case Insensitive in Symfony

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

What i need

- Username : ABC@gmail.com  email address stored in db &  input  will be lowercase.
- there is no canonical field  which has lower case email address stored.

The solution

```
     select * from view   where trim(lower(username))=trim(lower(input_username))
```

I read Url  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html

security.yml

```
providers:
    entity_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
```

## property: username

I have commented out property as i need to call loadUserByUsername in repository.

Service.yml

```
app.repository.user_repositry:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    autowire: false

    autoconfigure: true
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments: []
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

Repository code

```
            class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
            {

                public function loadUserByUsername($username)
                {

                    return $em->createQuery(
                            'SELECT u
                            FROM App\CORE\Entity\User u
                            WHERE LOWER(u.username) = :query'
                        )
                        //->where('LOWER(user.username) = :username')
                        ->setParameter('query', strtolower($username))
                        //->setParameter('query', $usernameOrEmail)
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getOneOrNullResult();
                }
            }
```

Problem occurs

```
  You must either make the "App\Entity\User" entity Doctrine Repository ("Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository") implement "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface" or set the "property" option in the corresponding entity provider configuration."

If i set Entity Abstract class then My app stops working

    namespace App\CORE\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
   use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;

    /**
    * @ORM\Table(name="users")
   * @ORM\Entity
    */

   class User  implements UserInterface,\Serializable
```

After fixing eror making enity abstract causing issues.

```
   //abstract class User extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface,UserInterface,\Serializable
```

if i change enity to abstract my application not working.

- any suggestion can i implement without making entity class abstract.

Refrence

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html

[How to do username case insensitive in login form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183229/how-to-do-username-case-insensitive-in-login-form)

Comment: oracle sir problem in Oracle db 12c

Comment: Configuration is slightly different for a [custom user provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider).  You basically need to explicitly provide the service id.  The example you followed with just the entity would work if the entity was correctly mapped to the user repository AND if you defined a service with the repository class name as the service id.

Comment: And your service file is messed up.  You should be defining a UserRepository service, not a generic Doctrine entity repository service.  What Symfony version are you on?  Autowire can actually make you life easier.

Comment: If you use something like `->setParameter('query', strtolower($username))` you have to be careful. `strtolower` is not unicode-safe. You could use the new Symfony String component for this: `u($username)->lower();`

Comment: symfony 4.4  followed  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html

Comment: As mentioned in my earlier comment, you don't have your UserRepository mapped properly to your User entity.

Comment: Yes problem resolved  , customer provider  working

Comment: can  anyone tells full query loadUserByUsername  which symfony uses for login_check

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FOSUser](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php) approach with `canonical username and email`

1. Add additional field && save the canonical value
2. Use canonical field to search user

   ```
   public function findUserByUsername($username)
   {
       return $this->findUserBy(['usernameCanonical' => $this->canonicalFieldsUpdater->canonicalizeUsername($username)]);
   }
   //------------

   public function canonicalize($string)
   {
       if (null === $string) {
           return;
       }

       $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
       $result = $encoding
           ? mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_LOWER, $encoding)
           : mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_LOWER);

       return $result;
   }
   ```

Comment: Front end Angular 9 Backend Symfony 4.4 as API login :/login_check

Comment: please can help in  full query loadUserByUsername  which symfony uses for login_check