# Convert Å Ä Ö to A A O

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace accented Latin characters in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby)

Is there an easy way to convert any letter that is not equal to a-z to a-z?

I want for example convert `Ü` to `U`, `Ö` to `O` and so on, I dont care about upper and lower case letters.

This is what I've so far.

```
{"ä" => "a", "å" => "a", "ö" => "o"}.each do |from, to|
  string.gsub!(/#{from}/i, to)
end
```

But I don't want to specify every word.

Any ideas?

Comment: I take that comment half-way back. Apparently that solution over there uses a Rails method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more general solution than `String#tr`, look at the stringex gem. http://github.com/rsl/stringex

Answer (score 2):

Use the [tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001199) method.

```
 string.tr!( "äåö", "aao" );
```

Comment: I guess it's way easier to use Unicode normalization and just strip out diacritics.