# Executing Objective-C from Ruby on Rails

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to execute the following Objective-C code in my Rails application:

```
CFMutableStringRef inputString = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, 32,     CFSTR("общей"));
CFLocaleRef locale = CFLocaleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("ru"));

CFStringTransform(inputString, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics, false);
CFStringLowercase(inputString, locale);


NSLog(@"%@", (NSString *)inputString);

CFRelease(locale);
CFRelease(inputString);
```

It basically outputs a lowercase, diacritics-free version of the input string. I am running on a Snow Leopard server.

How can I do this (without using MacRuby, which seems to be an overkill here)? I've heard of Ruby extensions but can't find any resources in my case.

Comment: This really seems more like a pure Ruby question: "how do I strip diacritics from a string?". Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225471/how-do-i-replace-accented-latin-characters-in-ruby

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple... I need to use the native Objective-C functions because I'm dealing with non-latin strings too (Hindi, Mandarin, Russian, etc.).

Comment: @alste: Somewhat pedantic, but there's no Objective-C in the above. You're using constants and functions from Core Foundation, which is a C library. Anyway, can Rails call out to a binary located on the filesystem? If so, make the above its own little utility, then call out to it as needed, passing the input string as an argument. Note that if you do that, remember not to use NSLog() because it's so noisy.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've considered that, but I would have to call the binary thousands of times (when inserting new foreign words into a database, for example - I would want to store their lowercase/diacritics-free version). Is there a more native way to call Core Foundation functions from within Ruby?

Comment: What about creating that little app that using named pipes and then you can use the pipe to write/read?

Comment: Also, Ruby (especially 1.9) can deal with non-Latin characters quite well. You probably don't need Obj-C at all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an app you need to be spawning on and off in a single Rails instance you can write your app using other ways for communication, like named pipes:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041025103920992
http://www.pauldix.net/2009/07/using-named-pipes-in-ruby-for-interprocess-communication.html

Or going the Ruby C extensions way:

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html
http://people.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/ruby-extensions/ruby-extensions.html

Comment: ruby extensions is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it using [`ffi`](https://github.com/ffi/ffi), but it'll require entering a bunch of function specs.  Tiny test case for calling a Core Foundation function:

```
require 'ffi'

module CF
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation'
  attach_function :CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent, [], :double
end

puts CF.CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent
```